# Cleaning up questions overrun with low quality answers

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Every once in a while I bump back into this question: [Can I use one model inside of a different model in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980556/can-i-use-one-model-inside-of-a-different-model-in-cakephp)

It's grown a bit out of control over the past few years.  The majority of the answers are from new users and have poor formatting and grammar.  Worse, they don’t add anything new.  Out of 15 (now 14) answers, 6 of them tell you to use `ClassRegistry::init()`, 3 tell you to define associations, and 3 don’t solve the problem in the question.  6 answers total score negatively.

Here’s the steps I took to clean it up:

1. Flagged it for protection.
2. Commented on the low quality answers explaining what could be done better.
3. Downvoted any answer that was "not useful".
4. Flag as low quality 4 duplicate content answers from users who’ve gone dead.
5. Edited any post in need of polish to encourage a standard of high quality.

I’m looking for a bit of feedback, since the protection flag is over a week old and half of my “low quality" flags were disputed.  Was this a great way to handle the mess, or is there anything I should have done differently?  Is there any further action that should be taken at this time?

Comment: I've protected it for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking care of that! The flag asking for protection has been sitting around for 10 days now.

Comment: Yeah, that question is a complete mess. I'll vote to delete some of the answers, but since I'm not a PHP person, it's hard for me to judge what should stay and what should go.

Comment: @Mysticial I think any new answers to a years old question that has a obviously well-regarded (yet non-accepted) answer ... are fair game.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a question like that, with as much cleanup as there was to do... I would've once suggested lots of flagging.

But *daaaamn!* Having a real meta appears to have prompted folks to come here and *take care of business!*

So... Next time you find yourself staring at a veritable *Augean Stables* of a question, kick off a meta discussion.

And Mysticial, Makoto, Brian Roach: way to step up to the plate!

Comment: Yes, posting to meta in this derelict of a condition took care of the problems way more efficiently than those flags did.  Must be the consequence of putting the full post into context.