# A user is continuously and rapidly proposing invalid edits (adding tags) that get robo-approved

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I'm going through the edit queue and I have encountered the same situation 3 times already, out of 4 reviewed edits.

User [brainy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3611023/brainy) is adding a single tag to the question with the exact same comment: `Added (tag) because it related to the question`, where `(tag)` is the tag he added.

Each time the tag he chooses appears literally as word in the question but has little to do with it otherwise (definitely not enough to add the tag). It almost seems like bot behaviour, and that is backed up by the high frequency and long-time period (8 hours today already) of his suggesting edits, as proved by his reputation history.

Even if he does this manually, I think he needs to realise that adding a single tag is usually not a substantial enough edit and that he needs to learn what tags are for exactly.

What shall we do?

Comment: If his reputation is low enough that his edits still need to be approved by the review queue, just reject the edits as invalid. There are, as far as I'm aware, automatic processes in place that will result in his ability to suggest edits being removed temporarily if it happens enough times.

Comment: 198 rep from edits yesterday and 200 rep today... But the problem are the reviewers, not the user.

Comment: @Manu wow, I didn't even go see his rep history, but that improves my confidence that it is actually a bot.

Comment: Not necessarily a bot. Just a rep-farmer who knows there are review-farmers out there willing to let him abuse the system. Although, 20 seconds between suggestions does suggest some sort of automated behaviour, true.

Comment: Does rolling back also remove his ill-gained rep?

Comment: @Jongware: [No](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back).

Comment: @Matt that's strange, wouldn't removing that rep be similar to rolling back the effects of serial upvoting? Anyway I think the benefits one gets from reviewers doing a plain bad job shouldn't be kept.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: I still stand by what I said in [my answer to the question I linked to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137759/163863). The problem is that it takes 3 reviewers to accept an edit, yet only one person to roll back. The system ***has*** to assume that 3 people know better than one person. The problem here is the *reviewers* accepting the edit in the first place, not the person for making the poor edit.

Comment: @Matt They are all problematic, the person doing the numerous, often invalid, edits and the reviewers. Abusing robo-reviewers isn't better than said reviewers.

Comment: If we trusted low rep users to make valid edits, we wouldn't need reviewers.  The problem is a new user learns that these types of edits are acceptable because he has submitted them in the past and they get approved.  Not everyone frequents Meta so they don't understand what actually constitutes a good edit.  If the user gets told what they are doing is wrong and they don't stop, then they need to be held accountable.  Before that happens though, the reviewers need to be held accountable.

Comment: Is this a case for the audit system? It seems it would be fairly easy to create some useless add-a-tag edits and feed them to reviewers.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Good idea, maybe we could ask Brainy for the script he is using, at least that way some good would have come out of it.

Comment: @Matt and psubsee2003, the fact that _only_ the robo-reviewers are guilty for the negative effects only holds true **if** the invalid edits are a genuine mistake in the first place. The user making these edits is effectively **spamming**, he knows the edits are wrong and he's doing it to farm rep. He is deliberately abusing the system. In fairness, no one would attempt to farm rep this way if no robo-reviewers existed, but the way this user is cashing in on this flaw **should be recognized as a problem in its own respect**, IMHO.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: ... and if the reviewers were doing their job and rejecting the edits, the problem would be fixed, as the person would stop making the edits **and**/**or** get banned from making edits. FWIW, [I've pinged the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059471/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-privacy-settings/24059590#comment37256975_24059590) and alerted him to this meta discussion. It's likely he doesn't even know he's done anything wrong, *or* that there's this discussion about his behaviour.

Comment: @Matt Yes, if reviewers always did there job this wouldn't be a problem, but you need to recognize that reviewers *aren't* doing their job so this *is* a problem.  SE either can't or won't fix the problem of bad reviewers (which, granted, is a rather hard problem to solve) so tacking the problem from both angles, of both trying to kick out bad reviewers and also preventing bad edits from being suggested, becomes an option worth at least investigating, in the event that it's a problem with solutions that are more readily available.

Comment: Are rep farmers even a thing? I hear a lot of people worrying about it, but I don't often see them.

Comment: @TankorSmash It might be a difference in how you define a rep farmer. For example, some people might think it's rep farming if a 20,000 rep user answers CSS questions like "how do I center content in a div" which have been asked 50 times before on StackOverflow, and some people might think that behavior is okay.

Comment: Has anyone noticed his profile text says "please delete me"

Comment: @TylerH The problem with that is that it's a duplicated question that should be closed, rather than trying to answer the dudes question, is that right? Regardless, I don't expect everyone to be aware of all the existing duplicates.

Comment: Sounds like the [same problem I had last week](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258327/handling-floods-of-too-minor-suggested-edits).

Comment: @TankorSmash Right, such questions should be marked as duplicates, not answered for continual rep increases, and we expect such high-rep users to know this. It's true that new users/low-rep users don't know of potential duplicates, but they *should*, and it's *our** fault for not enforcing a culture where new users are pursuing quality answers and knowledge. * - "our fault" meaning "the site's fault".

Comment: There are other users doing the same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5028309 Looks like someone has created a bot and is sharing it.

Comment: I [attempted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119790/wordpressshow-dynamic-sub-menu-in-frontend#comment37210957_24119790) to ask for more substantial edits from him yesterday. He ignored me.

Comment: @TecBrat Hey good find, that's something odd too.

Comment: Some dude (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1628280/zefnus?tab=reputation) figured out he can suggest two consecutive edits to get +4 instead of +2: one to remove a burninated tag, another to add an almost synonymous one.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I would make a seperate question for this on meta stack **exchange**.

Comment: He is doing the same thing you described but has improved the algorithm basically doubling his gained rep. He's also been penalized for serial upvoting (-1500 rep) a while ago, so he might be the brains behind the automation.

Comment: I've removed Brainy's added tags several times. They have had nothing to do with the specific questions. The funny thing is that I can count on his worthless edits to be on questions that get the most of my editing attention.

Comment: [Rate limit suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210416)

Comment: Is hitting improve, changing something minor and unchecking "suggested edit was helpful" a valid approach?

Comment: @awesomeyi absolutely not, suggested edit was not helpful and why would you change someting minor anyway?

Comment: Many months later, this sort of thing is still going on... I just flagged an edit by user [Vvk Aghera](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4395049/vvk-aghera)  for moderator attention, hopefully they'll be able to sort it out. Nothing wrong with occasional edits to add a tag that's missing, but many of these (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566113/objc-searchbar-makes-status-bar-transparent)) are clearly blatant rep-farming attempts and almost his single source of recent "income".

Answer (score 25):

As noted in comments/linked posts, one thing you can do is to flag one of their posts or a post they edited, and use "Other" and let us mods know. Sometimes there are other things going on with this type of thing, too; we'll look into it. As otherwise noted, a large part of the problem here is the Robo-Reviewers. Ugh, is all I can say about that.

But also don't forget that you can notify *any editor* active on a given post via comments - just use `@<username>` and they'll be notified - for bad edits made in good faith, simply *communicating* is often enough. All too often, folks let this go on too long for fear of speaking up. Just be polite and have a spirit of helpfulness.

But, I think [Patricia Shanahan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1798593/patricia-shanahan) came up with an [interesting idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260042/a-user-is-continuously-and-rapidly-proposing-invalid-edits-adding-tags-that-ge#comment40067_260042): to have review audits include this type of edit; where a word in the question matches an existing tag that's not already in the question, but no other edit is done.

*But*, I think there would also be a lot of potential for this to cause audit edits which would actually be quite valid, though minor. Perhaps there are some algos which could rip that chance down to near zero, but also, I'd wonder how common this type of edit is, to know if it'd be worth trying that.

Comment: These types of edits are *very* common, and when people spam serial bad edits, this is one of the more common types of edits to spam.

Comment: Oh, and there's not really a compelling reason to remove the generated audits that would be too minor, because people also shouldn't be approving edits that are too minor, so it's just not a problem either way.

Comment: @Servy Good to hear, from someone who reviews edits much more than I do! I can imaging these would be somewhat frequent, since it seems like they would be easy.

Comment: The main point is coming up with some sort of search criteria to find posts to edit, which is why the two most common are generally posts in a tag that should be removed, or particularly keywords (in which the keywords are words to be removed, like "thanks", or common misspellings to be corrected).  Almost anytime you see any other type of serial edit its still something to which some criteria is selecting them all.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case, communicating wasn't enough. [He ignored me yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119790/wordpressshow-dynamic-sub-menu-in-frontend#comment37210957_24119790).

Comment: @Andy Unfortunately, some users do not take polite advice. There are numerous reasons why, of course, and I can't go any further here due to specifics in this case. Suffice to say, attention has been brought ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Fair enough. I just wanted to let you know that I'd attempted the polite route.

Comment: And it's very much appreciated, @Andy :)

Comment: We could make review audits where the added tag is an obvious meta-tag or has the "DO NOT USE" in it's tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Oh, now that is a *fantastic* idea, I think!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Wow, thanks! I've now [posted it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260185/create-too-minor-review-audits-that-consist-of-adding-a-bad-tag) as a feature request.

Comment: I already did that yesterday or so, flag is still "active"

Comment: @PlasmaHH Don't worry about that; we have a lot of flags. Action has actually already been taken on that user. And FYI; you didn't need to flag after posting this, as we're already aware of it. But I'll go find and clear your flag as helpful now.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I don't know if I flagged before or after this post, but it wasn't as a reaction to it. I stumbled over this user after about a dozen "this edit has already been approved" messages when trying to reject it in the review queue. I just saw this on the community bulletin

Comment: Flag? Great idea! "declined - We can't edit ban people: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits"

Comment: @bjb568 We can't edit ban, no; but we can do other things. We can send messages, for instance. And it could be that the current status of that account has something to do with this post...

Comment: @AndrewBarber Is temporary suspension really useful in this case? I mean he can keep the rep afterwards. So for him, it was still worth it, he just has to wait a few weeks.

Comment: @kapa I can't really discuss specifics on this kind of thing. I can just tell you we're taking measures appropriate to what is going on, and we often follow up on things. But also note [the user's profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3611023/brainy). "Please delete me"

Answer (score 11):

I have seen many users abusing this with manual edits, adding some insignificant tag to a question just to farm rep.

The solution to this problem seems obvious: make it so that edits that do nothing but changing some tags don't get rewarded with reputation points.

Comment: Wasn't it so that at a certain reputation you get the `retag` option under a question and you can do that without reputation gain? Anyway I like what you suggest, adding tags is scriptable and it's not always obviously invalid.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: yes, but at that level of rep, you already look like someone who knows something instead of someone who added random words out of the question body as a tag

Answer (score 0):

Suggested edit that only change a tag is invalid for users with low rep. Because the edit should be substantial to OP. I thought reviewers handled those invalid edits and rejected them. If you are not on the reviewer chain and you see that someone made an invalid edit you can fix it by opening edits of the post and rollback to the previous state. If the user continues to make edits on it or rollback an invalid edit you can flag on the post and as already said here use "Others" and add your comment. Mods are in care of such things, but unfortunately not all things handled by mods as you might see "declined" or "disputed" status of your flag. You might try to resubmit a flag again, or forget it.