# Generate new types of audits for the Suggested Edits queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-audits

The Suggested Edits queue still suffers from people who are too happy to approve things. The current batch of sloppy reviewers have learnt to Reject the current audits in the SE queue, but often don't look further than that.

I believe this can be solved by better review audits.

In the LQ and CV queues, audits are created by looking at highly upvoted posts and using them as audits. This has sometimes lead to poor review audits, as sometimes very poor posts still gather a lot of upvotes.
To avoid this in the SE queue, we shouldn't take audits by automatically sampling from a pool of approved and rejected edit suggestions. The audits should be generated.

I already suggested once to [create review audits that consist of adding a bad tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260185/create-too-minor-review-audits-that-consist-of-adding-a-bad-tag). This request contains a few other ideas.

Possible Suggested Edit audits that could be generated:

- Edits that replace links with nonsense links or spam links. The nonsense links could be shortened links to an SO page telling the user the link was invalid. (Congratulations, you checked the link before clicking "Accept" or "Reject").
- Edits that **boldface or italicize random phrases** or put `Product Names` in code markdown.
- Edits that mistakenly format code. Indenting or un-indenting lines for languages where indentation has meaning, like Python and Haskell.
- Edits that deliberately introduce grammatical errors - replacing "you" with "u" and "I" with "i".
- Edits that add "this doesn't work", "thanks" or "did you find a solution for this?", and similar things that don't belong to the post itself.
- For regex questions, edits that appear to be an answer to the question. They add "Use this:" followed by a regex. The regex itself can be any standard regex for phone numbers or e-mail addresses.
- For tag wikis, content that is directly scraped from Wikipedia.
- Edits that remove system messages like "Possible duplicate" from a post.
- Edits that inline links to `example.com` . Some editors recklessly inline everything. `example.com` is the canonical example domain - so when an OP uses this, it's clear they want to show the format of a URL, and do not intend to provide a link.

There are probably a great many other Suggested Edit audits that could be generated. I would like to see such audits added to the Suggested Edits queue.

Comment: +1! I would suggest adding "adds 'thanks'" to your second to last point. I've seen that often enough.

Comment: I so hate suggested edits that do these things... I see a lot of the random phrases/product names one.

Comment: the audits in the suggested edits queue are insanely easy to spot, to the point where even robo reviewers can still bypass them with ease I'd wager. I've seen at least a dozen now and they're always large scale vandalizing edits. This game really does need a better challenge.

Comment: I just stumbled upon that, too. At first, it's really strange, then you basically go "ah, another review" as soon as you see some random garbage in the edit...

Comment: Would it be possible or even feasible to include copied content tag audits in the Suggested Edits queue?

Comment: @twernt To catch the robots who approve plagiarised tag wiki contents? I suppose it's possible, but it would be harder to implement than the options I've considered here. It would probably involve scraping Wikipedia.

Comment: @S.L.Barth That's what I was thinking. There is a lot of obviously copy/pasted content getting approved in tag wiki edits -- almost all of it is on previously empty wikis. I'd be happy to help out with this, but I have no idea how the audits are actually implemented.

Comment: Moreover, it currently takes some (observable) time to generate an audit review. When a review page does not load in one or two seconds, I am starting to think: “OK, another audit coming.”