# Why are review audits in Suggested Edits queue really obvious

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-audits

Is it just me or are the audits inside the Suggested Edit queue really really obvious that they are tests.

This was raised as an issue [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272518/2357233) by a user, but hasn't got a satisfactory (or any) answer.

Even if someone was robo-reviewing, the obvious insertion of random words  destroying sentence structure, grammar, and post clarity makes it really super obvious that this is a test.

The test in question was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6928397). As soon as I saw the pattern of edits, I lept for the reject as spam option, because it was immediately  obvious that it was a test.

Surely it would be beneficial if tests were more subtle, to wake robo-reviewers up?

Comment: I remember seeing a suggested edit mentioned here that was approved that inserted a link to a porn site and added the text "Stack Overflow sucks".

Comment: That is quite amusing. Imagine trying to explain that to the person monitoring your internet connection at work.

Comment: @PeterJ: That's just because the reviewer agrees that the site sucks and is vetting such edits in an attempt to contaminate the site.

Comment: Audits are *designed* to be obvious. Once you *notice* that it's obvious, you have pretty much passed the audit. I think you place too much faith in robo-reviewers - I count at least a dozen users failing suggested edit audits in the last 24 hours - that's one every two hours on average, and with the kind of stuff that you're seeing right now. Make them any more subtle, and the risk of false positives will skyrocket.