# Do question edits being sabotaged by malicious bots?

Tags: discussion

Every not-so-often I spend a few minutes going over the "Suggested edits pending approval" list. I noticed during the past year that some edits contain text that evidently was added randomly from a dictionary, w/o any relationship to the original text, or with blatant grammatical errors.

Is SE being sabotaged by malicious bots? As there is no advertising or active URLs involved, what is the benefit of those who do that?

Examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12122175

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12122086

Comment: Aren't those audits that you should reject?

Comment: Those are audits: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: Yes, of course they are, as I put in my question "pending approval". I am just curious as to why and how these get into the queue.

Comment: They're audits placed in the review queue to catch robo-reviewers who aren't paying attention. Some people actually approve those edits, earning them a review ban. There's no bot that actually made a bad suggested edit.

Comment: Are these audits computer generated?

Comment: Why is the author "Community"?

Comment: @PetahChristian - so are you saying this is a SE deliberate behaviour, built into their review mechanism?

Comment: @ysap Yes, it's absolutely deliberate. It's not an actual edit made by anyone (person or bot). It's a fake edit -- an audit designed to look like an actual suggested edit -- to see if people are paying attention. Obviously you noticed they should be rejected, but not everyone passes that test. Hence the bans to catch people who regularly approve edits that should be rejected.

Comment: OK, I agree that this question (in some variations) was answered before, but is it just me, or do the people who marked it as a duplicate of this question (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285206/why-are-review-audits-in-suggested-edits-queue-really-obvious) did not really read my question? Obviously the two questions ask different things, where the other one is concerned about the *quality* and *effectiveness* of the audits, while mine was inquiring about the existence of the system... Go figure... There are definitely better duplicates in meta.SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are audits. They're not real edit suggestions. They are inserted automatically into review to see if you're paying attention.

And as crazy as it may sound, people actually *approve* them. 
The system keeps track of that. Approve too many of these obviously destructive fake edits, and you will get a suspension from reviewing - you will not be able to review for a while. And rightly so - anyone crazy enough to consistently approve vandalism like that, has no business reviewing.