# Meaningless edits, or formatting guidelines not communicated?

Tags: discussion, edits

I receive notifications of ‘suggested edits’ to my writing with cosmetic changes of unknown purpose, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9150476):

[image: Screenshot of suggested edit]

A common pattern is that an edit looks like it tries to make my answer or question conform to some formatting guidelines I’m not aware of. Invariably I can’t reject it because by the time I open it it’s already been unanimously approved.

What’s going on with these edits? Are there any formatting guidelines that I should follow but am not?

Comment: This particular edit was completely pointless and should not have been suggested, let alone accepted. There was _zero_ point in italicizing those spots. Looks to me like someone just editing to edit.

Comment: And the review stats of those reviewers says it all.

Comment: Looks like they improved your post. Move on.

Comment: The random italics is really bad.  The line breaks in the css code are meh (but superfluous).  That's a "no improvement whatsoever" edit.

Comment: Are you unable to roll back edits once they've been approved?

Comment: @BSMP, thanks for the reminder. Forgot about that functionality for some reason.

Comment: The edit made your CSS easier to read (for me, anyway). I suspect that was the inspiration for the edit rather than some guideline (that doesn't exist, as far as I know).

Comment: @Cypher - I get the motive for the line breaks in the CSS, but what's with the italics? It's not a research paper; there's no reason to use ALA or MLA style citation for just someone's name.

Comment: @BSMP I agree. The italics do not add anything. But that's our opinion, and you know what they say about opinions. :)

Comment: @Cypher you shouldn't force them on other people's posts while farming rep? :)

Comment: Yes, the line breaks make a cleaner read.  The italics? Maybe a *minimal impact* way of reaching the minimum number of changes to allow the edit. Necessary edit? Not really.

Comment: I absolutely expected that a whitespace-only edit will not be accepted as longer than 6 chars. But it was, when I just tried, by suggesting an edit indenting the css code again. (Maybe he expected the same, and made up some irrelevant extra changes to comply with the form? )

Comment: Of interest to read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302450/424903

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I personally don't see anything wrong with the format of your post.  I think your post is the victim of two separate but connected actions.

First you get a user who is doing suggested edits to get reputation and/or badges.  Then you have people in the review queue that are rubber stamping everything (robo reviews) and unfortunately they are processing these edits.

Looking at the user who made the edit they seem to be getting a lot of reputation from edits and when I took a casual glance at some of them I would have rejected them. If you look at the review history of the first two users they have no rejects which is suspect to me as there should be an occasional edit rejection.

I think it might be appropriate for a mod to take a look and a timeout might be in order for all.

Comment: I would caution that the [reviewer's stats on the review page might be really inaccurate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272597/suggested-edits-showing-the-wrong-stats).  But in this case, just from browsing their profile's activity tab, I think you're right.  [For example, Reviewer 2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/307072/arbejdsgl%C3%A6de?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

Comment: Yes I reviewed their review history from their profile.  I know not to trust the stats served up in the queue.

Comment: I figured you did, but maybe others viewing this post don't know that.  I didn't really want to edit this into your answer, but I though it was an important footnote.

Comment: I've "communicated" with a couple of the reviewers.

Comment: @BradLarson I am truly curious about what sinister action your scary quotation marks imply. Did you communicate by means of a horse's head in each of their beds?

Comment: You are correct !

Answer (score 4):

About the edit in whole

It would be okay if a 2k user improved formatting, even if it's a very minor improvement. But thousands of 2k users have read the text and no one ever bothered about formatting. So there was no urgent need for such edit. **For a reviewed edit this is just not enough.**

**About the details**

- *@username* in italic — NO, usernames should stay in regular text.
- *SoftwareName* in italic — NO, just the same, no need to emphasize
- HTML/CSS properties<sup>1</sup> one on each line — YES, it's much easier to read this way.

(1) Don't know the right name, correct me if it's wrong.

Comment: Normally I'd agree that CSS properties should be on their own lines, but in this case, each line had related properties, so the readability hit really wasn't that bad. Making even that change was pretty dubious, and given that the rest of the post showed reasonable quality, not really justifiable.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I totally agree that it's not justifiable, especially for a reviewed edit. Added a note about it in my answer. Also, now I see that properties are grouped in lines, but it wasn't obvious to me because I don't specialize in CSS.