# Improve review Suggested Edits "paying attention" algorithm

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

From my current observations, "paying attention" checking test (audit) during Suggested Edits review is just placing random words into edited post, which are very easy to find out.

I think that algorithm needs improvement, which could involves previously Rejected edits with 3:0 votes for vandalism, attempting to reply etc.

Example review [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10779563). I have improved [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608506/asynchttpclient-header-error). Few mins later, I saw that FireSun suggested edit on this post (probably he started before I saved my edit). Anyway people almost accepted this suggestion. As we can see, there is no improvement comparing to my edit, also text *Pls help idk what to make...* has been added.

Comment: Not sure why you think it is bad audit - skip/reject/reject&edit are the only valid options I can see - all 3 should pass audit as well as make sure you at least glance at the post before robo-approve.

Comment: I just think that algorithm need to be improved. Like in ex. *Low Quality Posts* you don't pass audit where you selected that post looks OK, where it has been deleted already. Some kind of audit should be added to *Suggested Edits*  - not only added random words proposed by *Community* user, but also previous cases.

Comment: I have clarified in question now that audit = test during review;

Comment: +1. I have [suggested some other types of Suggested Edit audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272518/812149) a long time ago.

Comment: That's bad no one from staff replied in your suggestion. I hope this time they will notice it.