# Providing feedback on approved bad edits to my answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25922527/revisions shows unnecessary and arguable negative-value edits to my answer.  One of the reviewers correctly observed this and commented to that effect, but the other reviewers (who made no comments) approved them anyways.

As the author of the answer, I would like the ability to review the reviews, and in particular provide feedback to the reviewers who have approved bad edits.  Ideally, one should be able to down-vote edits, and these would have a negative effect on reviewers who make poor decisions.

This issue only adds to my frustration with edit reviewers.  I had a review of mine rejected, only to observe a substantially identical edit by another user approved.  The standards for editing reviewing on this site are woefully inadequate.

Comment: So, what exactly are you asking here? Edits like that can just be reverted with an explanation. You could also place a comment on the post, @notifying the person that made the incorrect suggestion.

Comment: @Cerbrus He already reverted the edit before coming here. But I can see the frustration - people making one's post look silly. @ Jeff, Cerbrus _is_ right that you can @-notify the editor, who probably assumes they're helping. Assume good faith from the editor.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw the review approval notification but there was no mechanism to comment or @-notify the reviewers.  Did I miss that?

Comment: @Jeff No, you didn't miss it. It is a less-well document of SE that you can @-comment editors. They don't show up in the auto-complete, but you can @-comment them.

Comment: Coming up with an edit standard to dictates when and where back-ticks should be used is a completely lost cause.  Little point in making this a drama, just roll the edit back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you already found, you can always revert edits that you disapprove of. If the same user keeps making these edits to the same post, you can flag for moderator attention - edit wars are not allowed.

But we should assume good faith from our editors. Many of them  truly believe they are helping. The fact that there are approval-happy reviewers isn't helping, of course - if editors are rewarded with +2 rep for edits like these, the signal they are getting is "Hey, well done!" instead of "Sorry, no".

When an edit to your post is made, you get a notification in your inbox. As the author, you have a binding vote.
In this case, you only saw the edit after it was wrongfully approved, but if you had been there before the approval happened you could have vetoed the edit.

You can @-comment editors. The auto-complete does not work for people who edit, so it may be best to copy-paste the user name. In this case the user has a space in their username, which would be reason for me to use copy-paste.
The editor may not respond immediately, of course. I believe that the two of you are in a different timezone, so don't expect an immediate response.

When contacting an editor, *assume good faith* and be nice. It's frustrating to see one's posts changed into something one doesn't agree with, but the editor is probably under the belief they are helping.

Regarding the review process, that has long been a topic of debate over here. The Suggested Edits review queue, to which you will gain access once you have 2000 points, has long suffered from people who are too happy to approve nearly everything. I have long ago proposed to have [more types of audits in the Suggested Edits review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272518/generate-new-types-of-audits-for-the-suggested-edits-queue), and I still believe this could drastically improve things.

On closing, reviewing can be a somewhat arbitrary process. If we could give rigid guidelines about what is and what isn't a good edit, we could automate the process. As it is, we have to resort to humans for reviewing.