# How is it possible that this edit was approved?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, review-abuse

I'm talking about [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14318961).

It clearly changes the code in the answer to something that no longer solves the problem. The previous code was what OP wanted, the edit changed it to something that no longer answers the question correctly:

- Old Revision:

  - `undefined == null` was `true`
  - `null == null` was `true`
- New Revision:

  - `undefined === null` is now `false`
  - `null === null` remains `true`

I don't understand how this edit was accepted?

Comment: Because the edit audits are super easy so people don't bother reading past "oh? Not an audit? I'll approve".... HOORAY FOR ROBO REVIEWS

Comment: _"How is it possible that this edit was approved?"_ Easy, three people clicked approve. Why did three people click approve? Well, less easy. Could be they weren't paying attention/robo-reviewing, could be they _thought_ the code was the same, could be aliens...

Comment: Could be some people need banning!?

Comment: the approve/reject rates for those reviewers are telling  ...

Comment: Mhm, do I schmell review bans? :)

Comment: @Patrice That's why I suggested [more varied review audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272518/812149) for the Suggested Edits queue.

Comment: what's more irritating is when people edit code in questions, and in doing so they fix the issue the OP is trying to solve. Have seen several of those accepted before...

Comment: This is just a heads up that the approval of this edit didn't go unnoticed by mods, and the approvers have been... *dealt with*.

Comment: Believe me..I am facing this daily..rejecting but bingo some other robo reviewers  will approve..just for badge dude..just for badge.

Comment: Because edit reviewers are so busy dodging audit traps they don't have time to do what they think they set out to do.

Comment: This is why it is much better to "Reject and Edit" then just "Reject".  If you just "Reject" it is quite likely that three robo-reviewers will accept.  If you "Reject and Edit" SO assumes you have fixed what the editor was trying to improve, and their edit is no longer appropriate.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You must be new here!

Lots of bad or incorrect edits get approved, all the time. Sometimes it's due to negligence, laziness or "robo-reviewers" trying to get their first badge.

Sometimes it's an honest mistake. In this case, frankly, the answer is so poorly annotated that at first glance and without a thorough understanding of what the answer was *trying* to say, the edit may appear useful and good.

I'd say the original author, the editor and the approvers are equally at fault here.

Fortunately, the fix is simple: roll back the edit and improve the answer to clarify that the double-equals is *intended*, and to explain why.

As it happens, Aerovistae's answer (currently in second place) is *much* better, providing the same solution but with annotations and explanations. The bigger question, then, is why *that* is not the accepted and most-highly-scored answer. For that, we need to look to a different Stack Overflow pattern, that the masses appear to appreciate brevity and simplicity over, well, the truth.

Comment: *"a...Stack Overflow pattern, that the masses appear to appreciate brevity and simplicity over, well, the truth."* While this is often accurate, it's more of a democratic voting pattern than a Stack Overflow pattern. Everyone has an equal vote, but not everyone has equal knowledge. In fact, the majority of voters are insufficiently qualified to assess the technical accuracy of an answer, qualification of a political candidate, etc. Yet that doesn't stop them from voting. Flaw by design, unfortunately.

Comment: @CodyGray: This is also why less "democratic" forms of governance are not necessarily "evil", but often just an honest take on trying to find a better model. Again, though, this is too complex for the masses to comprehend :)

Comment: "I'd say the original author" interesting that you include the author, which most of the time gets ignored, since nobody ever asks its opinion on what their answers should look like.

Comment: @Braiam: Ultimately, this edit was made because the answer was unclear, and the responsibility for that rests with nobody but its author.

Comment: Well, the help center disagree with you: Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include: [...] To *clarify* the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)

Comment: @Braiam: _"Without changing that meaning"_... this edit **completely** and **entirely** changed the meaning of the answer (and made it the _wrong_ answer in the process). You've fallen into the very trap of which I speak.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not sure what you are getting at: you say that the answer *was unclear*, the help center says that "clarify the meaning", Shog says "Editing is a form of communication!". So, the author posted a unclear answer, if someone clarify it's meaning isn't that a good edit?

Comment: @Braiam: No. It seems like you haven't actually compared the two versions of the answer. There was no "clarification" here whatsoever — only breaking! **The edit broke the answer, fundamentally and completely...** to the degree that the answer: (a) correctly (if unclearly) answered the question before the edit, and (b) _incorrectly_ (and still just as unclearly) answered it afterwards. The answer was and is unclear because there was no annotating text, not because the original code was a random selection of arbitrary characters.

Comment: Ok, let me set some things straight, because I believe that we are talking past other: this edit should have been rejected on technical merits, not because it was editing code, we agree on that, right? Now, if someone with the correct technical expertise wants to improve the answer, they should be able to do so.

Comment: @Braiam: Yes, of course. Nothing in my answer disputes that, so if that's what you're talking about I don't know why!!

Comment: If you read my first comment, you say the author is at fault, which community agrees, which I find funny, because "most of the time gets ignored".

Comment: @Braiam: I really have no idea what you're talking about, but that's okay :)

Comment: No problem, [you aren't the only one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338986/why-was-my-clarification-of-the-answerers-code-rejected/338994?noredirect=1#comment418722_338994)

Comment: So, I tried to do exactly what this answer says, to have it rolled back? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2647888/revisions

Comment: @Braiam: I agree, and don't know what ssube is doing. Perhaps writing an edit summary to explain your action may have cleared matters up? Between the original answer and your edit, a third-party observer is likely to have no idea whatsoever what's going on!