# Bad edit in review queue

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-audits

Lately, on the tag I frequent, I've noticed that numerous edits that I rejected still got accepted through the review queue.

Example: [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17850945) (someone edits in code formatting for table and form names, not code) was quickly accepted.

<sub>Note that the reviewers accepting it have a reject rate of 2.0% and 8.9% of all questions reviewed, and even lower improve rates.</sub>

I was wondering: should I revert edits like this that went through the queue (even though they have been approved by 2 reviewers)? And should I take further actions (modflag to notify the reviewers for example)?

To prevent this in the future, we could  introduce more difficult audits, like  S.L. Barth proposed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272518/812149)

Comment: Personally, I think that is OK to format those as code. Those are not part of natural language, but identifiers you use in code. Not that I'm a fan of this edits: the question was bad to begin with, and the edits did nothing to address the other glaring problems for the post, nor the main issue of the question not being good enough (as in it probably should be closed, not edited). At least it was edited *before* the post got closed, and not after.

Comment: I have [proposed generating new types of audits for the Suggested Edits queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272518/812149), long ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Should I revert edits like this that went through the queue (even though they have been approved by 2 reviewers)?

This particular edit, I'd leave it. There are a number of issues with this edit, but nothing that rollback will solve.
First, the edit doesn't fix the grammatical problems.
Second, it uses `code markdown` for names, but those names are technical artifacts. Whether we put technical artifacts in code markdown or not is something we leave to the OP's preference. The OP can choose to roll back. (As a side note, I much prefer code markdown for this over boldface or italics. Putting these things in boldface or italics makes me itch to Reject.)
Third, as has been pointed out, the question is low quality; only the OP can improve it by giving more information and showing what they've tried to solve the problem.
In its current form, the question is not yet ready for the Reopen queue, so better not to edit it until the OP improves it.

In general, if a post is otherwise good and an edit uses markdown wrong, by all means roll back. My personal pet peeve is people putting product names in code markdown, or introducing grammatical mistakes. These I'll rollback or edit in shape.

- Should I take further actions (modflag to notify the reviewers for example)?

If you see a pattern of bad reviews, you can flag one of the OP's posts and use a custom moderator flag. You should provide a few examples of recent bad reviews, so the moderators have sufficient material to judge the reviewer.  As a rule of thumb, look for 3 bad reviews in the last 2 days. The moderator can then suspend the reviewer and, in case of suggested edits, overrule the review.
Expect some time before a moderator handles the flag; the moderator queue is quite full. And flags about bad reviewing are apparently some of the more labor-intensive types of flags for the moderators.

A more elegant solution is to approach the reviewer directly, and explain to them that you disagree with their review. However, the result of this depends very much on the reviewer. Some will take your advice to heart - others will raise drama.

Comment: I'd like to approach the reviewers directly, unfortunately, this is difficult on SO. If they're not in chat, and haven't responded to the post, there's no proper channel for me to contact them.