# Tag adding flood by a user

Tags: discussion

Can someone please stop [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2094275/jason-wray) from just adding the very same tag on each question he gets?

He has ~30 approved edits for the very same thing, which is obviously not that ok - the tag isn't always about the question people ask, as it's "google-maps-ios-sdk". Sometimes people just ask questions **without** that sdk.

And what's the best practice here, how to report such a behavior, post here or what?

Comment: If he is adding erroneous tags then I would flag one of the posts that are being approved...he and the reviewers need a timeout in the corner. If that is all that is wrong with the post and it is correct then accept. If there is much more wrong with the post (most likely is) then...REJECT REJECT REJECT!

Comment: I've already rejected like 5, but as I can see he continues with that and he does it with a great pace!

Comment: I understand your frustration, trust me, but that's all the help I can offer. I constantly reject bad edits just to see them approved. Maybe someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Since he has had so many accepted edits, pick one and tell him to stop.  While the auto-complete won't work, you can manually type in `@jason-wray` (actually `@jas` will work too) and explain why you think what he is doing is incorrect.  If he doesn't stop, at least you tried.

Comment: Refer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260042/a-user-is-continuously-and-rapidly-proposing-invalid-edits-adding-tags-that-ge

Comment: Do you have an example of a question where the tag is inappropriate? I've looked at a bunch and it *seems* to make sense (for example, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23820740/revisions - the removed tag was bad because it was about the JavaScript API; the code and the new tag are about the iOS ObjC API). Obviously, as user who must have his edits reviewed, he *should* be addressing all issues in the posts - not just changing tags.