# User keeps improperly using code tags - and getting approved

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

[A certain user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3508489/mrmojorisin) is misusing both `code ticks` and *other* **formatting** elements to [highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5159863) [names](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5159962) of [software](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1406263). [Literally](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1406253) [almost](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1405996) [every](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1405987) [approved](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1405892) [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1405875) (there are [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3508489/mrmojorisin?tab=reputation)) is misusing code tags.

Does the [flag a mod's attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260042/a-user-is-continuously-and-rapidly-proposing-invalid-edits-adding-tags-that-ge) still stand? What is the currently accepted action to take?

I feel like I've done that before and the flag was declined with a message about misusing the moderator attention flag.

More importantly, what is being done to combat this? Just as an experiment today, I decided to open every suggested edit I declined in a new tab to see how many were approved. Out of the ones I reviewed, all but one were approved (these were trivially easy declines, and were very bluntly irrelevant or bad edits).

I feel like the 20/day cap and audits are just minor, patchfix-type attempts to stop robo-approving. What else is in place to stop this?

---

**EDIT:** This has turned into a [feature suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262364/use-specific-guidelines-as-suggested-edit-audits).

Comment: I often go back and check the suggested edits that I've rejected until I need to sit in the corner, curled up in a ball, and crying over how ugly it is.

Comment: @codeMagic I already called in my prescription of lithium :(

Comment: Clearly not enough, to answer the question you asked.  This has been well known to be a problem for a long time.  A number of changes were made over a year ago to turn the system from "completely unusable and causing a net harm" to "very often takes the wrong action, but still has a (small) net positive effect".  Since then, there have been no noticeable changes to suggested edit reviewing.

Comment: This one is somewhat unusual as he is fixing some formatting problems in a very intelligent manner.  It feels like he knows exactly what he is doing and is just looking for posts to farm rep.

Comment: Heat up the review banner!

Comment: @psubsee2003 None of those suggested edits are acceptable.

Comment: I understand review audits are supposed to thwart robots, but what about improving audits to throw questions that focus on one aspect of the guidelines, and if it is approved soft-ban the user's reviewing abilities for a few hours while directing them to the appropriate page/post about that review item?

Comment: I feel like a portion of most of the suggested edits are acceptable and beneficial. There are places where he fixes list formatting, or correctly uses code tags. My guess is that the reviewers saw more harm than good coming out of the edits, which is why they got approved. Not sure [what happened in this case that you already mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5159962). It ALMOST got rejected! :)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Sure, there are a few that he suggested that are perfectly fine. The *majority* that were approved are just terrible.

Comment: @Qix Making specific review audits that explain the specific reviewing error sounds good to me. You should make it a [feature-request].

Comment: @Qix I never said any were acceptable, you are reading too much into my comment, however for you to say none are acceptable is a stretch.  Some do improve the posts.  They may not be perfect, but they do improve some things.  For example, I fail to see the problem in the [3rd one you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5159902)

Comment: Misuse of inline code formatting is a pet hate of mine too, though I'd guess some people actually think it is appropriate.

Comment: Relevant; http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text

Comment: @JoeBlow: What?! No, it's not unclear at all. This post is _very_ clear. The only person who's even mentioned spam is _you_, which I find somewhat ironic.

Comment: Lightness -- fair enough, I'm still missing something. What's the guy "doing wrong"?  Is he "sucking up for points, but doing so using crappy edits?"  I want to punish this villain, but I don't follow you yet.  (Obviously everyone else does, I'm missing some secret knowledge.)

Comment: I deleted my comment which mentioned s p a m, lest someone be unfairly impugned.

Comment: @Joe, inline formatting is for code, not for general highlighting (e.g. for emphasis). Some people insist on emboldening for every proper noun, which is plainly wrong, and detracts from readability. The motivation is sometimes thought to be rep-hoarding, even though the edits are of debatable quality.

Comment: @halfer .. AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH -- sorry I suddenly understand what the hell you are talking about.  **Thanks so much** for explaining that.  I just had no clue what you guys were talking about, thanks.  Well yeah, that person is an a-hole, just edit it away surely?

Comment: (I suppose it's just conceivable that the person in question does NOT REALISE what he is doing.  I would leave a nasty message every time, explaining what he is doing wrong -- really clearly.  Eg, "DO NOT USE CODE FORMATTING FOR EMPHASIS." sort of business.  Thanks again

Comment: It's quite funny that now you've explained the topic under discussion to me .... your headline and the first sentence actually perfectly express that  :-)

Comment: Looks like Community♦ has finally [turned](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5159885) against us...

Comment: I agree with all his edits.  Sometimes users unfamiliar with technical terms don't understand where a phrase is supposed to begin and end or that a term is a technical term at all.  It bothers me when people turn my edits down because I emphasize technical terms using tags or code blocks.  IMO, that's what tags and code blocks are for.

Comment: @Wolfpack: well, now at least you know that the community broadly does not like code tags being used in this way. Everyone has to modify their pet writing style to some degree, just like adopting new coding standards when joining a new programming team. If you feel strongly about continuing to use inline formatting for term definition or emphasis, please raise a new Meta topic and ask whether it is OK (or take it from this topic that it is not OK, if you prefer).

Comment: @halfer thank you.  Yes, it's useful to know that this just isn't proper etiquette.  What I've been doing recently is actually linking out to term definitions, man pages, etc., to accentuate keywords.  So, I can't say I feel strongly about this from a writer's perspective.  And from a reading perspective, I can see how it would also be annoying to see too many tags (for example, when I read on Yahoo! News, all the linked definitions are a nuisance).  Experience programming eventually catches people up to what is a technical term and what is not, anyway.

Comment: @S.L.Barth [Done.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262364/use-specific-guidelines-as-suggested-edit-audits)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Our primary tool is simply sending the user a moderator message, which I have also done. This lets us identify specific behaviors with the user, explain why they're inappropriate, and hopefully improve their habits in the future. However, edits being approved is not entirely the editor's fault. If their edits had been rejected appropriately, they would have hit an edit ban that stops them dead in their tracks, and would have told them to review their suggestions to find out why they're being rejected. **This is also the reviewers' fault.**

More recently, moderators gained the ability to add custom messages to review bans for users. This allows us to explicitly identify a post that we want the user to look at in order to understand why they were banned, rather than just throwing a "you're banned" message out and expecting their behavior to change.

This is exactly what I've done here. I've gone through every suggested edit the user made, found all the truly terrible ones, and banned 26 reviewers for a day (24 hours), pointing out the particular reviews that they shouldn't have voted to approve. Many of these reviewers showed up multiple times across different reviews (and a couple of them had already hit an automated block for failing audits).

Generally, we do prefer you flag cases like this for moderator attention and include as much detail as possible, simply because we don't really like when you call out specific users here on Meta (that's why we actively destroy the [specific-user](/questions/tagged/specific-user) tag whenever it pops up - that's not something we want to encourage). I would suggest finding one or two of the most atrocious examples you can and then mentioning that many of their suggestions follow a similar pattern. It should trigger an investigation.

Keep in mind that we *only* recommend flagging a user for their editing behavior if there is a **clear pattern of abuse**. If they made one or two bad edits, especially if they got rejected, please don't bother us with it.

**Also related:**

- [Moderators should be able to manually ban users from suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/moderators-should-be-able-to-manually-ban-users-from-suggesting-edits)
- [Flag users who approve an edit that ends up rejected for vandalism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194571/flag-users-who-approve-an-edit-that-ends-up-rejected-for-vandalism)

Comment: Personally, I don't think it is terrible if we draw attention to a specific user, so long as it is handled fairly - such is the basis of an open community. No user need fear being linked to from Meta, and of course a complaint appearing on Meta is not automatically upheld.

Comment: @halfer I think there are two concerns with that: 1) The user may be targeted by someone overzealous, and 2) even a "fairly handled" public complaint is a higher risk of degenerating into something like a flame war if someone gets upset.

Comment: In This Case Is The User Spamming Ads For Some Software?

Comment: @JoeBlow: Sorry I Couldn't Read Your Comment Because Your Baffling Employment Of The Shift Key Hurt My Brain Too Much

Comment: Sadly flagging often doesn't work well, presumably because of the moderators being overloaded and thus not seeing the big picture. I have the personal feeling from my experience that those flags are quite low on the priority list too. That said, well done for going through all the reviewers!

Comment: But I think having moderators handle the few things that stackizens stumble over will leave the majority of crappy and robo-approved edits unhandled, and it should really not be the duty of a moderator to do all this. In the past weeks lots of meta questions/feature requests to add "AI" to various parts of the site, e.g. to catch more bad reviewers by better audits. I don't know whats behind the scenes , but before we contemplate weeks about what is the best solution we should start doing *something* and try some of these ideas; we can still scrap them when they don't work.

Comment: Light - funny :) but, there's some "shared knowledge" or something I'm not getting here.  My point was Lets Be Clear... {Not that it matters or anything; I'm just curious.}

Comment: I think I'm one of the "banned" for the day reviewer. I don't consider myself a robo-reviewer as I take time to check each edit I review. I just did not know that just highlighting some words is incorrect. In the future I will reject with too minor reason. Thanks for pointing it to me.

Comment: @AlexV If we thought there was a serious problem with robo-reviewing versus just not realizing something, you would get banned for longer. One day is just the minimum that lets us tack on a note to teach someone. It's great that you paid attention to it.

Comment: @animuson, I agree there are overzealous users. But if such a user brings their hobby-horse to Meta, in some cases they might be told they need to tone things down a bit. Better that than undetected cases of overzealousness going on under the radar.

Comment: @AlexV: a very positive response, good stuff.

Comment: @AlexV Don't feel bad, really. The concept of mis-using code tags has kind of been out of the limelight until recently. Now you know, and now you'll make better choices in the future :)

Comment: To highlight a bit of why to avoid singling out specific users, there is [evidence](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3508489/mrmojorisin?tab=reputation) that suggests someone is going out of their way to downvote all of this users posts

Comment: @bengoesboom Those votes will be [automatically reversed overnight](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/237313), so whoever's doing it is just wasting their time. Still, not "naming and shaming" would have removed the temptation.

Comment: @halfer When there's a target to research, it's more difficult to isolate the issue.  Other variables get involved as a specific user is researched, so the issue is less likely to be dealt with in a generic way.