# Use specific guidelines as suggested edit audits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review-audits

As of late, I've noticed a lot of really poor suggested edits being approved (either through robo-reviewing or otherwise) with little recourse towards the approvers and lots of time spent rolling back changes, re-editing to improve, and sometimes flagging repeat offenders.

I recently [posted a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261708/user-keeps-improperly-using-code-tags-and-getting-approved) regarding issues with robo-approving and `code ticks` specifically, and suggested this feature in a comment. It received a few upvotes and someone suggested I submit it as a feature suggestion.

There are a [few](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258397/can-we-make-rejecting-suggested-edits-easier) [suggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260185/create-too-minor-review-audits-that-consist-of-adding-a-bad-tag?rq=1) already floating around, but one improvement I haven't seen proposed is to **target specific suggested edit rejection reasons as individual audits**.

Right now, the only (or the prominent) auditing method is to test for rejection due to vandalism. This is great, but mostly obvious, and the intent is simply to thwart simple bots or those not paying attention.

Such audits were made to assess **quantitative** evaluation, not **qualitative** - which brings us to this suggested feature.

---

I propose the introduction of a new class of audits that test for rejection reasons in particular, in accordance to certain suggested-edit guidelines.

- As with vandalism audits, the posts used in audits will be *obvious* and require *100% rejection rate* for the *same rejection reason*.
- Users who fail an audit are soft-banned from reviewing for a specific amount of time (TBD, see below).
- Failed audits will not only result in soft-ban, but will direct the user to a help page that identifies *why* they failed, which reason the failed audit was assessing, and ways to identify such issues in the future.

**Why the instant ban?** The ban is not intended to punish the user, but to ensure they take the time to read guidelines on reviewing. This is because most new reviewers (or even some veteran reviewers) haven't actually taken the time to understand what makes a good suggested edit.

Due to this, I propose a 1 hour soft-ban upon failing one of these audits in addition to directing the user to a help page.

---

Examples of potential audits (along with number of approvers):

- [Invalid Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5199331) - Approved by 2
- [Invalid Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5186888) - Approved by 1
- [Invalid Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5180540) - Approved by 2
- [Radical Change](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5199332) - Approved by 2
- [Radical Change](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5205000) - Approved by 2
- [Too Minor](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5198237) - Approved by 2
- [Vandalism](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5159897) - [Approved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261708/user-keeps-improperly-using-code-tags-and-getting-approved) by 3

<sup>Pulled from my history since it's the easiest way to find them. *These are just examples;* I'm sure there are much better edits for these audits.</sup>

---

In conclusion, not only would this feature **reduce the rate** of incorrect approvals, but **educate reviewers** regarding reviewing guidelines and what is considered an acceptable suggested edit, as well as potentially **lowering rollbacks** or moderator intervention.

Comment: `As of late, I've noticed a lot of really poor suggested edits being approved`, Man, welcome to the party.

Comment: Just want to mention there are only so many synonyms for the word *suggest(ion)*.

Comment: A downside to this is finding the posts to feed the audits with. Otherwise, this should be a good idea.

Comment: I found 7 in about 10 minutes by going through my own review history. Further, like I mentioned in the post, a few heuristics could be used to find potentials automatically.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't categorize that last edit as vandalism. They added unnecessary formatting and collided with an earlier edit in a way that removed the last paragraph, but that isn't outright defacing the post. The reviewers at the time probably wouldn't have seen the last paragraph change, just the backtick formatting.

Comment: @BradLarson, yeah, that was grounds for my original post. It's been debated as to what the backtick abuse should be categorized as, and as you can see in the edit I linked I usually use a custom comment anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this was to be done, I'd prefer that the audits still be procedurally generated, not requiring human intervention to select and label them. I'm not yet ready to deal with outrage on Meta because moderators picked subjective audit cases, especially without [a good system to contest those audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188780/review-audits-and-i-understand-button/188790#188790).

Inserting random backtick formatting for words should be easy for the audit generator to do, as well as cases of randomly inserting nonsense code fragments into code blocks, and maybe deleting random paragraphs. These would seem to cover the three types you identify above. The system could randomly switch between each of these audit types and the standard gibberish ones per audit.

Independent of that, I do agree that better documentation about the function of each review queue and what to look for there could be presented to reviewers. Per-queue help documentation could maybe show examples of bad edits, etc. in the same style as the intro help center shows good question samples. This could be presented to people on their first visit to the each review queue, and linked to via a ban message if they trip audits.

Comment: `This could be presented to people on their first visit to the each review queue` +100

Comment: "Per-queue help documentation could maybe show examples of bad edits, etc. in the same style as the intro help center shows good question samples."  As a newly-minted first post/late answer reviewer, yes please!  The help text when reviewing isn't very helpful and there's no link to get more help (or at least, it's not obvious enough).