# Foreshadowing of suggested edit audits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review-audits, review-abuse

When the system gives you an audit in Suggested Edits, one of those
vandalism-type edits, it’s *really obvious* that you’re going to get one
of those, because it takes several seconds for it to come up, much
longer than any real review task.

Seems to me this would work particularly badly at catching someone who’s
just clicking away without paying attention, because a user like that is
going fast, and they will notice when the system slows down like that.
Once they’ve seen it happen a few times, they’ll know they’re about to
be audited before the edit even comes up.

So, why not generate them in advance instead? Every hour or so, generate
maybe five of them, toss out the ones that have been used more than *n*
times, repeat. No delay means no warning. No need to keep track of who’s
gotten which ones, because you only get about one audit per day anyway.

I’m asking this on SO Meta because that’s where I’ve had the experience,
but I imagine it applies to the rest of the sites too.

Comment: And yet they still work to catch robo reviewers so why waste time making them any better when the target audience won't notice the change.

Comment: @RobertLongson Do they? I don’t know where to find that data.

Comment: Other questions on this very subject and their answers.

Comment: @RobertLongson I’ve seen several other questions about suggested edit audits, but I did not see any addressing this particular point. And even if the data suggest that robo-reviewers are being caught with the current system, that says nothing about how many more might be caught with this revision.

Comment: @TomZych I think we'd catch a lot more robo-reviewers if we had better audits in the SE queue. I've suggested adding [other types of audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272518/812149) to that queue. Also [this suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262364/812149) for picking unilaterally rejected edit suggestions might work. Quite frankly, I'm aghast that people manage to fail the current edit audits at all, other than by mis-clicking.

Comment: I've never noticed this pause, personally. Maybe you're going too fast? ;-p

Comment: @Don'tPanic I've noticed it. For me it takes maybe 1-2 seconds on clicking to go to the next review. Audits sometimes take 4-6 seconds.

Comment: @Machavity interesting. I'll probably start to notice it now that it's been pointed out to me. But somehow, even as unobservant as I apparently am, I don't think I've ever failed a suggested edit review audit.

Comment: brief skimming of [discussions about manual review suspensions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breview-suspension%5D+manual+is%3Aa) made me feel that maybe audits for suggested edits are less efficient compared to other queues. Per-queue statistics for the ratio of manual to automatic bans would probably help to confirm or disprove this impression

Comment: It's been said time and again that the point of an audit is to make sure you are simply *paying attention*, not performing a specific review action that may or may not be the best review action. If you are noticing that the next thing to load is about to be an audit, and you are able to handle correctly, then you are clearly paying attention and therefore being audited 100% successfully according to the point of the system.

Comment: @NickA Ah, good catch. I added the suggested-edits tag to make it easier to find.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug)