# Same pattern of editing which doesn't improve the question

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

Today when I started reviewing the suggested edits. I came to a problem where I have 10 consecutive suggested edits from the same user and the edits doesn't improve the post much.

I approved it first time but then consecutively same suggested edits comes next.

Here are the links of the suggested edits.

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7395600
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7395609
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7395663
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7395671
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7395674
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7395675
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7395678
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7395684
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7395690
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7395692

My question is, what should I do in this kind of scenario where users picks the same question set and edits a question with the same "KEY Formatting" comment?

Is this kind of behavior is ok? 
It should be approved or rejected?

Well I approved it 1,2 times but most of them I rejected.

Comment: I've been rejecting them as well. Not only do they not improve the post very much they are all edits to very old questions (which will get bumped if the edit goes through). It might be worth flagging to a mod although I suppose the user will eventually get edit banned ... unfortunately many of them have already been approved ...

Comment: There are almost 300 edits (key formatting) from this user for old questions, most of them have been approved :/

Comment: Yeah. Mostly his edits are approved and it is strange that he uses the same pattern for almost all the edits he had made so far.

Comment: Related question [User keeps improperly using code tags - and getting approved](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261708)

Comment: Flagged appropriately to a mod

Comment: Left a comment for that user to notify him/her of this post

Comment: Thanks @rene for triggering me. You can remove the other comment now that I'm on this thread. Let me say I didn't know this was against the rules. (And actually I do not yet see it clearly is.) I agree, it is not a hell of an improvement, but still a small one. Formatting is one thing but this as well adds semantic markup. I recently came across several posts which lacked proper formatting and added the <kbd> tags for better readability. I figured it was an easy way to search for posts like this, so I did and worked towards my Copy Editor Gold badge with this...

Comment: I did not see this as a problem as I'm not harming anyone or the posts and improve readability for users and maybe crawlers. Editing old posts is no crime as well, there even is a badge for it. The linked question regarding code formatting is not completely comparable. I am not misusing the formatting like described there. I'll keep from further doing this (not that I did this 24/7...) and see what the outcome of this here is.

Comment: In fact I already thought about asking this question myself here on meta since I was not sure about if it is OK, so I'm glad you did.

Comment: @udondan I'm trying to find a better meta-post but the help center says [Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). In general we say Fix everything in one edit. If someone else has to edit the post after you, you basically missed a couple things to improve.

Comment: @udondan in the past there was a reject reason specifically for edits such as yours: "too minor". This was removed by SE during the latest revamp, for reasons which a huge number of users (at least of meta users) disagree with. Your edits need to be reviewed by at least three users, better make it actually worth their time and fix actual issues in posts worth editing. Also, an edit bumps a post to the front page where it takes away space from other questions. Refrain from making trivial edits, especially on questions nobody cares about; and don't go on a search spree for minor issues.

Comment: I'm not too much in meta, so I don't know what went on there. But if a reason gets removed, doesn't that mean it officially is not a reason any more? Also, if this is community managed I suppose it means the majority decides and the majority seems to agree with those edits as they got approved, no?

Comment: Regarding the frontpage: Is seriously anybody looking at this? I don't see this page useful in any way as it's a soup of posts which are unrelated to my interests. I would be more concerned about posts being pushed in tags which got subscribed by users. So yes, this argument I would let count. (On the other hand, subscriptions are broken and bump me posts every day which have not been touched for months. But OK, that's not an argument).

Comment: From my perspective it all comes down to the question if the improvement is trivial. And hostly I am tempted to say _yes_. But then I would say the same about punctuation, grammer, spelling and changes which remove "thx", "regards" and that like. Part of that even is encouraged by the available help text. IMHO the same can count for formatting, if it is used correctly and improves readability. And in this case it even adds semantics, which is not a bad thing. People are being picky about using quote vs. code correctly but don't care about kbd?

Comment: Another thought: @Joker approved 2, and I have seen others first approving and later rejecting changes. (yes, I followed the reviewers behavior, it's a nice social experiment) So the thing that disturbs you seems to be not the change itself, but the masses. Maybe we should focus on that as well: Is it OK to actively search for posts for the only purpose of editing them to gain reputation/badges? I think if it wasn't, there would be a filter from keeping you doing this, like 1 edit per X minutes, only X edits per day, only count X reputation of edits per day,... There is nothing like that.

Comment: @udondan The change of edit reasons, just like the change of close reasons, was decided by SE and only communicated after the fact. Yes, it is not an _official_ reject reason anymore, but the problems I mentioned don't go away by removing the reject reason. Of course they also apply to other edits like capitalizing "i" to "I", removing "thanks" etc that just fix a few very small issues. And editing _is_ rate limited by time, you can only edit once every 30s or you'll get captchas. Also, if your motivation is rep/badges instead of _improving the site_, please refrain from editing anything.

Comment: @udondan see also [this related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262813/bumping-question-after-editing-feature-should-be-removed) and the answer by BoltClock, quoting: "I suggest you simply only edit posts that are in need of editing and put more time and effort into making your edits more substantial."

Comment: See, I never got that rate limiting captcha. That's because I actually read the posts and edited accordingly to context. If I noticed other things, I tried to fix that too.

Comment: The thing is, the docs simply are not clear. On one hand it tells to "avoid trivial edits" but just a few pixels away it tells to "correct minor mistakes", "fix grammatical or spelling errors" and "clarify meaning without changing it". What is trivial and what not is up to interpretation. And when the majority of people approves these changes, then the majority seems to think it is not trivial. After all it **is** adding to the readability of the posts. Unless it is written black on white this is opinion based.

Comment: Argumenting to not do something for reputation/badges on a site which **only** works through exactly that is not quite logic. Remove badges/reputation and I promise you will loose 95% of daily active users by tomorrow. Pretty much everyone here is **only** doing things because of that. Remove the badges for reviews and I expect none of you would ever had seen an edit suggestion in the first place.

Comment: If you want to keep people from doing things like this, then _you_ should remove their incentives, in this case badges and reputation. Remove the incentives and you will see posts only being edited if they really are hard to understand due to missing code formatting etc. - If that's the goal, why are there badges like Copy Editor and Archaeologist?

Comment: See, I totally get your point. It might be annoying for some users due to how things work here. But I don't see it is clearly against any rules. There is no rule for not editing old posts. There is no rule for doing edits for reputation. It's not clearly written what qualifies an edit. That points to a problem in the rules or the system. So don't blame me personally here. :) Just to make it clear, I don't plan to continue with this now that I know it troubles you. But others did and others will. And I don't see a problem here other than those caused by the system itself.

Comment: @udondan *"On one hand it tells to "avoid trivial edits" but just a few pixels away it tells to "correct minor mistakes", "fix grammatical or spelling errors" and "clarify meaning without changing it"."* I don't see how changing Enter key to <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key corrects minor mistakes, fixes grammatical/spelling errors, or clarifies anything. However, I think the only harm these edits are doing is the fact that your edits have to be approved by other people. If you were past the threshold where no one had to approve your edits, this question likely would not have happened.

Comment: I quoted those to reply to the argument that for example changing _i_ to _I_ is actually covered, even though it is a very minor change.

Comment: Adding a `kbd` tag sure is no grammar issue, but definitely clarifies what it is. If not for you, then at least for crawlers, it's a semantic tag. Have a look at [this change](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7382214) for example, and tell me it does not improve the readability. It does. I come from Google to this page, see those keys jumping into my eyes and immediately know this is either the same question I have or not. I don't have to waste my time reading the whole post before I get an idea of the topic.

Comment: Regarding the review queue, I disagree. People are craving to approve/reject edits to gain badges. The argument which I let count is that posts are bumped either for users which have tags subscribed or on the homepage. That really might be annoying.

Comment: The way I look at it is this. What are the problem with small edits that only make trivial improvements to posts? The answers seem to be (1) they take time for people to review them, (2) they bump the question to the "front page", (3) they reward editors with reputation points they may not really have earned. Perhaps the answer is to give reviewers the option of allowing the edit but awarding no reputation points to the editor and not bumping the question on the "front page". That would drastically reduce the number of trivial edits while still allowing small improvements to be made.

Comment: I'll reiterate what everyone except @udondan said, these edits do nothing to improve readability and are just for rep and badges. There might not be anything inherently wrong with that, but when you waste others time to review these edits, and wrongfully fill up the front page with old posts, it does far more harm than good...of which it does substantively none.

Comment: @udondan I looked at [your edit you said improved things](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7382214) and for me it made the post _less_ readable. My main editors are Emacs and Visual Studio, so I may not be in the target audience. However, the set of people who did not benefit (even restricted to non-reviewers) is non-empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am among those who disagree with the policy change. People with edit privileges should limit their rate of trivial edits to a few per day. People without edit privileges should generally refrain from such altogether. Those people should also steer well clear of tag burnination and retagging projects, as they can only slow them down.

Yes, the game here is fun, but remember: the main game here is not editing or reviewing. The main game is asking good questions and writing thoughtful answers. If the promise of rep points helps you do that better, that's great. But if you're *mostly* in it to pick up little point-dribbles and badges for minor cleanup activity, you should probably find a more rewarding hobby.