# What is the current position on minor "correct" edits?

Tags: discussion

I see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site) on meta seems to say that any minor edit that actually does improve the quality of the post should be accepted, and during reviewing I no longer see the ability to reject edits for being "too minor".  On the other hand I've seen many well rated meta [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258327/handling-floods-of-too-minor-suggested-edits) seeming to complain about reputation whores and seeming to say that people making too many should be flagged and will be handled by moderators.

What started my research was when I noticed the "too minor" reason wan't available anymore.  I Look at [the user's repuatation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1696030/volker-e?tab=reputation) and see some reputation whore-like behavior, for instance editing 4 separate answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495007/indenting-code-in-sublime-text-2/11543793#11543793) at one time, basically only adding `<kbd>` tags.

My initial thought was to reject the original edit in my queue because it was too minor, changing only spacing and a capitalizing an 'i'.  After reading up on meta I'm thinking I should have approved the edit (which is gone now) and that the users other edits actually did slightly improve the readability of the answers while not rising to the level of a flood which should be flagged.

Is there something definitive?  What is the current consensus in the community?  Should I just skip edits I deem as too minor and let someone else worry about it?

Comment: AFAICT, it's ok to capitalize the `I`s, even if that's all you do, and even if it's in a section needing a complete rewrite. (Can't think of anything more minor and useless but obviously correct just now.) Myself, I think that's not an edit which should be allowed.

Comment: There is a discussion on Meta.SE about this:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239106/what-should-be-used-in-place-of-too-minor

Comment: Keep in mind that multiple edits no longer risk pushing someone's work into Community Wiki mode, sheerly out of too many hands in the kitchen, so it makes sense that even a minor grammar & spelling improvement is worth retaining for future Readers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar opinion like you. Just few character changed - it should be too minor. But after discussion with Robert and Lightness Races in Orbit on meta [What should be used in place of “Too Minor?”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239106/270165) - I've changed. :-) So even, if it is a small change - does it improve the post? If yes, then why not approve it? Do you really care about +2 rep for the guy? He needs to do it 1000 times to get to 2k, and thats it, no more...

And if you feel differently you can always Reject with Custom and write your opinion there...

But I'm quite new here, and may not reflect the opinion of the community...

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this you need to flip the question around and ask yourself:

- is the edit outright *incorrect*?
- could the edit have been *more correct*?

If you think one of those conditions have been met then you can reject with a custom reason, you can physically type the words `Too minor [because of...]`. This will only take you a few seconds longer than choosing a pre-canned reason.

If those conditions above are not met then the edit is correct and there is no fundamental reason to reject it. Not everyone is rep whoring, some people just have a thing with lower case `i` being used incorrectly, so they will fix it. This is still a valid edit - especially where there is nothing to make it *in*valid.

If you're still feeling some angst because you think the user is rep whoring and they should be spending some time doing more important things but you have no valid reason to reject the edit then just *Skip* it.