# What do I now do for a previously "too minor" edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I have been pointed to this post when I asked what happened to the "too minor" edit reject reason:

- [Disappearance of "too minor" -- where is the relevant discussion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270961/disappearance-of-too-minor-where-is-the-relevant-discussion)

It of course links to:

- [Approve as too minor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039)

I read through those posts, and now I do not know what to do on the edit review queue anymore.

---

If I see an edit that previously would have been "too minor", what am I meant to do now?

Approximation of a case in point:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5794763
  [image]

Some capital letters have been added to the post. Previously a definite case for "too minor".

It has been pointed out that "Project" is incorrectly capitalised, which makes this exact one "invalid edit".

But I'm after the general rule - what if only "What", "Eclipse" and "There" had been capitalised? In the past that would be "too minor". Now days?

---

Now, if I understand correctly, I must either accept this as a good edit, or take the time to make my own changes. But in this case, there is very little else I can edit.

Comment: Should "Project" actually be capitalized in this context?  I wouldn't expect so, making this an invalid edit for that reason.

Comment: @Servy ok you got me on the details. What is the general rule though, that's what I'm trying to understand. Let's say he capitalised "What", "Eclipse" and "There".

Comment: You have to decide either to approve or not such edits. Here the added value is debatable, some people will say any minor added value is worth approving, others like myself would reject them as invalid or add a custom message saying it is too minor. The actual wording would be more "This doesn't improve the question/answer in a substantial way to be worth my time reviewing".

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Invalid edit says that the edit is wrong. Is that the intention now to call "minor" edits just wrong? Custom message seems very time consuming compared to the old method.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier See the duplicate of your previous question (and the Meta.SE posts it references).

Comment: @AndrewMedico I have read those, and referenced them up top, but did not see my answer there. Perhaps there's a subtle point somewhere buried in those threads that I missed - I'll try find it.

Comment: [Here's my reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239106/what-should-be-used-in-place-of-too-minor), see Shog's answer that too minor should be treated with Reject and Edit but no reviewer should have to edit on minor changes, so rejecting or approving are the options.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Thanks I missed that part - basically we just robo-review from now on.

Comment: If you don't know what to do for an edit, "Skip" it.

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce that's what I thought too, but I got through skipping 9 out of 11 before writing this post. Doesn't seem worth going to review if its just skip skip skip. If I'm not going to touch more than 80%, its not worth going in. So I came here hoping to find some definitive answers.

Comment: The SE community managers lately seem to be primary motivated by an urge to reduce the amount of complaining.  Complaining about that does rather defeat the intentions :)

Comment: @HansPassant Exactly why I am trying to get some definitive info from the higher rep users round here. Am I frustrated, yes, indeed; because I am confused by the rule changes and lack of direction on the issue. That said, there does seem to be some consensus on the various threads now.

Comment: You can add those 2, even if the change in the title could have not been made in the first place... they are too minor : [This](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5801182) 
[and this.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5801236)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Comment: Thanks @Henke, but no. I asked this question in Sep '14, because after asking that other question in May '14 I had not received a satisfactory answer. However I have noticed over the last 7 years that the "minor edit" wave has changed a few times.

Answer (score 4):

As per the linked discussions, the correct answer is found here:

- [Lightness Races In Orbit's answer on "What should be used in place of “Too Minor?”"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239155/188823)

> Does it improve the post to any degree? Accept it.

So in other words, edits that were previously considered as "too minor" can now just be accepted.

---

This attitude seems to be reflected in the much less noisy post here:

- [What is the current position on minor "correct" edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271135/what-is-the-current-position-on-minor-correct-edits?lq=1)

Gas seems to have reached similar consensus, after long debate with 2 of the more vocal people involved in this issue.

> does it improve the post? If yes, then why not approve it?

If I understand Slugster's response correctly, it seems he has a similar answer.

---

Andre Silva in his answer above also says "`genuine 'minor edits' are now, valid and my understanding is that in such cases, they are not considered bad anymore.`"

---

Andre  got downvoted for that answer, as I did for mine and Shog9 for his. Lightness Races in Orbit and Gas both have upvotes, ironically when I posted their info here I got downvoted for it.

---

Here's one of mine from way back in May 2014:

- ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site?rq=1)

Consensus then seemed to suggest that minor edits would be good, but that they have a cost. Perhaps the only thing changing today is that we no longer consider the cost to be too high.

Comment: Interested since I quoted the suggested source of all information that is good, why the downvote? Please suggest your own answer if I have misunderstood - I'm quite happy to accept downvotes, but the underlying issue is trying to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Lightness' answer is not exactly without controversy.  It attracted 8 downvotes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey and Shog9's attracted at least 16 downvotes. One thing I'm glad about is that there is at least a 101k diamond mod who is also confused by the new choices.

Comment: Richard, bottom line is, that it is really up to you. You have to answer the question - does it improve the post? :-) One reviewer will consider upper-casing 'What' and 'There' as not improving other could say that it fixes grammar, so it is improvement. I'd probably reject it, as I'm not that strict on wording and it doesn't improve the post in any either way... However I usually try to type custom reason instead of invalid, as beginner users may not understand why it was rejected. Something like "Changes don't improve the post" or "Too minor changes in the post".

Answer (score 3):

I think that the answer is very clear, if you want to follow what's intended by this change.

If the edit improves the post, approve it.  Yes, that means if they add (useful) code formatting you should approve it.  Yes, that means if they add a truly useful tag approve it.  (I still reject a lot of tag-edits because they add a stupid tag that doesn't belong there.)

If the edit is invalid/vandalism/etc., reject it for that reason.

If the edit is incredibly minor and doesn't fix a lot of other problems, such that you don't feel comfortable approving it, you have three choices:

- Fix it up yourself
- Approve it, if it still provides *some* benefit
- Skip it and let someone else fix it up

Skip is a *perfectly* valid choice here.  If you're skipping most of your edit reviews for this reason, either you got a weird batch of reviews or you're not really thinking this sufficiently through; even when Too Minor was a reason, and I was probably in the 75th percentile or so of minor-rejecters, I didn't have Too Minor more than 20-30% of my reviews, and now that i'm accepting a decent number of things I didn't accept before, I wouldn't use this more than a few times (caveat: I haven't reviewed a lot lately either).

I just did ten or so, and found 2 that I probably wouldn't have approved before due to 'too minor', but both were acceptable now I felt; in particular, [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5796355) which removes a quotation mark from the title.  I think you could justify reject/editing that, but I felt that it honestly was a useful edit (stray apostrophes are annoying!) and there wasn't a whole lot truly wrong with the question (you probably should do something with the rendered output section, but I couldn't decide what was best, and it looks okay as it is).

This is exactly what this was for: approve these edits, even though they're minor, because they *do* accomplish something.  I didn't see anything that I had to skip or had to revise, and like I said, I used to be a pretty heavy Too Minor user compared to (even the educated meta user) norm.

I think the big problem with this change (not that the change is bad, but why people have a problem with it) comes from two places:

- Change is bad
- Offended sense of justice

The former is just life, but the latter can be addressed - by ourselves.  You shouldn't have an offended sense of justice over the fact that people now get 2 rep for little edits.  First off, it's just imaginary points, so who cares.  Second, it gets them to a whopping 2k reputation.  Third, you know why they're getting rep?  It *trains them to think about editing*.  Even if they do stupid little stuff like removing apostrophes, maybe then later they will do *more*.  And sure, maybe we should figure out a better way to reward edits - reward only edits over 15 characters, reward only edits made on Wednesdays, whatever - but whatever system you built will be gamified, and honestly it doesn't matter that much.  People gamifying this system is *good* because it means they are *editing*.  As long as the edits are helpful edits, they're getting the right kind of feedback; and if they really are doing a lot of little crap they'll get enough reject->edited that they will at least vaguely understand there is something more to be done.  As long as they're not actively hurting things, it's not something we need to stop.

Comment: How is "Skip a perfectly valid choice" here? I would skip questions I don't understand, e.g. on a unfamiliar language. But if I understand everything and skip is the only option...

Comment: @TingL If you feel the correct answer is "Reject and Edit", and you don't feel like editing (the question specifically says ha has two choices, accept or take time to make edit), then skip is the correct choice.  Skip means "I don't want to review this", either because you don't feel sure that you know the right answer, or in this case because you don't feel like taking the effort to do the correct answer.  You then let someone else Reject-And-Edit, someone who has more time than you.

Comment: Still "Reject and Edit" is not equal to "Reject". The reason that I have to skip here is not because I don't have the time. The original post is fine. The edit is trivial but not invalid. If I reject-and-edit, would I be introducing another trivial edit?

Comment: If you are reviewing edits then you can make edits without approval process, no?  Then it doesn't matter. But the point: no, reject and edit a complete edit. If it's just one more trivial edit from being good then accept the trivial edit.

Comment: Sure, I have no problem with that. I will not babble more about this. But you misunderstood me apparently. It's not that I don't have the time or the privilege to make changes. It's that the changes are too trivial, and I don't feel right to accept it. Maybe as you suggest, I will skip on this.

Comment: My problem with this change is neither of the above 2, it is that there was no announcement that the rules have changed (in the sidebar on the main site, where they've been announcing something about a mobile site revamp for days now). After being bashed so much previously about not approving minor edits, and now we must approve them - it would have been a good idea to post about it in a way that casual meta users would have known about the change.

Comment: Your last paragraph is just a heap of baseless feel-good crap. "It trains them to think about editing"? - Maybe it also trains people to make a ton of useless edits, the review queue already has a ton of them. And "if they really are doing a lot of little crap they'll get reject->edited" is a baseless assumption; my gut feeling tells me most reviewers, me included, would rather skip those edits (as reject->edit is more work), while robo-reviewers approve them. People don't have an "offended sense of justice", they are fed up with the amount of crap on SO and the lack of tools to deal with it.

Comment: And another thing, I as a reviewer simply do not want to "reject->edit" an edit of a crappy question which should be closevoted and not edited anyways. I could reject all of these as "invalid", or to write a custom reason, but in practice I just want to reject thoose edits as fast as possible. Previously "too minor" was at least somewhat applicable here; every edit of such a post was too minor as it couldn't fix any of the basic issues making the question off-topic. Now I am left with no option that polishing a turd or writing a custom message - both cause more unneccessary work for reviewers.

Comment: I find it rather disappointing that you can say that having 20-30% of edits you be bad edits and *not think that that's a problem, or a lot of bad edits*.  If reviewers are wasting a third of their time reviewing bad edits and *approving* them that's *not* a good thing, it's not a negligible problem, it's serious.  Worse, that number will only increase, likely dramatically, as editors learn over time that very minor edits are good edits, rather than being trained to avoid them.  As minor edits get approved rather than rejected the percent of minor edits will only increase.

Comment: @Joe They weren't bad for entirely arbitrary reasons.  Very minor edits are harmful.  Deciding to approve them doesn't magically make them good, or those problems go away.  Now those problems are going to get continually worse over time.  And technically, according to Shog, you shouldn't be approving these edits, you should be rejecting and editing to actually make a good edit.  Approving them is still incorrect, despite the fact that tons of people (including you) are now assuming that the change is an indication that these edits are now perfectly fine.

Comment: @Servy What your comment says is "I disagree with the philosophical change."  We discouraged trivial edits *when the post was otherwise generally okay* before.  We don't any more.  That's what most of those were.  Yes, 10% or whatever still might require reject/edit or skip and let someone else fix them up more.

Comment: @Joe You think that 20% of the posts in the review queue are posts that are virtually perfect and have nothing that could be fixed up?  Really?  Or are you saying that you don't want to take the time to actually fix up 20% of the posts that you come across in the review queue so you're just going to let someone else approve them even though they should be rejected?

Comment: I'm with you re: the two "big problems" you identified, but I think you've missed a third one, which has to do with bumping questions to the front page that are substantially unchanged with respect to their content. That was happening before, too, but now it's policy, which makes it a bigger problem.

Comment: There is a 1k-rep limit from suggesting edits.

Answer (score 0):

**Update (08/Oct/14)** - most of contradictions now are solved with the [new reject reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239106/what-should-be-used-in-place-of-too-minor/240686#240686):

> no improvement whatsoever:
>
> This edit fails to make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

In the context of this question, minor genuine suggested-edits could be rejected as being **superfluous**.

---

I think with this upgrade, Stack Exchange is encouraging all types of valid edits, even the ones that are too minor (I mean, really 'too minor', not the ones which miss important details making them bad edits).

Until now, my experience as a reviewer says that most cases of former 'too minor' edits do miss other details, so they can be improved and rejected (or just rejected as "invalid").

If the minor edit does not miss anything else (capitalization, tags, etc.), then, they can be approved. On the other hand, if you still do not feel comfortable in approving, @JonathanDrapeau offers a good solution:

> ... others like myself would reject them ... with a custom message saying it is too minor. The actual wording would be more "This doesn't improve the question/answer in a substantial way to be worth my time reviewing".

Approving genuine "too minor" suggested edits have two main consequences:

- The question will be bumped to [active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions).
- The suggester will gain +2 reputation.

Both are not so problematic, at least on SO, because the traffic here is so high that questions quickly drop out the active tab. Therefore, answers on old questions would not have that much of time reduced from what we already have.

And if new users wants to gain reputation with easy edits, well, it will stop at 2k.

Comment: The fact that activity doesn't result in as much attention on SO because there is so much of it doesn't make adding more noise less of a problem; it makes it *much more* of a problem.  It's dramatically cutting down on what little attention *meaningful* activity already gets.  When everything gets plenty of attention either way it's actually *less* of a problem than when adding a few more items to the activity feed means *no* additional attention.  And rewarding users for performing *undesirable* behavior *causes them to continue to do it*.  We don't want people posting hundreds of bad edits.

Comment: @Servy, agree with everything you said. It is that genuine 'minor edits' are now, valid and my understanding is that in such cases, they are not considered bad anymore. Note, that in my answer, I write that most of former 'minor edits' will still be likely to be rejected.

Comment: @Servy, also I'd like to see an answer of yours addressing the following comment from the OP: `"@Servy ok you got me on the details. What is the general rule though, that's what I'm trying to understand. Let's say he capitalised "What", "Eclipse" and "There"`.

Comment: The edit is too minor, and shouldn't be approved, but sadly we no longer have the appropriate tools to deal with such an edit.  This forces us to either use a hack, and reject the edit for an incorrect reason even though the edit shouldn't be approved, or to approve it anyway.  In effect, every possible action the site makes available to us is wrong.  The appropriate solution is to have a "too minor" reason to reject that edit as.

Comment: @AndreSilva Servy has had a lot of input on the comments section of this answer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270971/383414 for what its worth.

Comment: @Servy, your comment is all correct. There should be a feature-request, requesting "too minor" to come back. The `improve and reject` button was a good idea, though. My answer just tried to emphasize what we can do without _hacking_.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, well, that's just, like, your *opinion*, man.

Comment: @AirThomas That's quite right.  It's an opinion that I've supported with evidence and reasoning, but there is a level of opinion included in the conclusion.

Comment: Would it be possible for SO to have separate "Posts with any significant recent activity" and "Posts with any recent activity" lists (the latter being for higher-level users only), and have minor edits bump posts in the latter [so higher-level users could watch out for patterns of abuse] but not the former?  The fact that a post has a typo which could be fixed shouldn't justify giving it publicity (from the point of view of normal users) but that shouldn't imply that the typo shouldn't be fixed.

Comment: @supercat, agree. I'd just propose something slightly different, for example: the "active tab" for bumping edited posts and a separate tab "new answers" for bumping old questions with new answers. It would solve some problems.

Comment: @AndreSilva: That could work too.  The main thing is that I constantly hear an argument that obvious minor problems with posts shouldn't be fixed because such fixes aren't sufficient to justify bumping reputation of the editor or the post's recent-activity status.  If a post contains a typo that one person thought was worth fixing, odds are good that until the typo is fixed, it will continue to be seen by more people, some of whom will propose the same fix.