# Suspicious approval of suggested edits

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was recently reading [Handling floods of "too minor" suggested edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258327/handling-floods-of-too-minor-suggested-edits) when I realized I had seen a pattern of such edits by a specific user recently.  Admittedly, there are plenty of this user's edits which I'd agree with, and I admire the determination to correct consistent spelling errors littered through SO questions.

That being said, this user has a clear pattern of performing *many* edits within a short span of time - systematically targeting a very specific spelling mistake (IE. "Funtion", "genrate", et al.).  These edits generally consist of only fixing the spelling mistake in the question title, sometimes within the question body, and rarely address other prominent issues that could be addressed simultaneously (if the edit was truly that necessary).

As mentioned, this is abundantly discussed in other threads. In perusing some of the more recent suggested edits, I noticed the following pattern of *Approve and Edit* by one user:

[Reviewed here.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8263798)

Also seen below:

[image: Screen shot of reviewed edit]

There were around 8 suggested edits by the user approved and edited by the second user. Why?  Of course, it's possible the latter coincidentally happened upon these edits before others could Approve/Reject, and genuinely thought these edits were worthwhile given additional attention.  However, nearly all of the *Approve and Edits* were similarly small edits to the title (rewording, spelling, additional word, etc.).

Is some type of action necessary here or is there something I've not yet understood about the process of approval that I need to know?  Don't get me wrong, I've made some edits that in hind site would rather have not suggested.  But not enough to consist of ~66% of my reputation.

Comment: I had to go to the 4th page of his edit list to find the first "Rejected". Oddly, a lot of the approved ones were approved by "Community". Doesn't she check for "too minor" edits? Most of them left plenty of other garbage in the posts.

Comment: I've rejected / reject and edited a lot of this user's edits as well. I think users < 2k should be encouraged to make as large of an edit as possible, because it takes reviewers. If the user is > 2k there is no rep gained and it takes no reviewers so I would say that for those users its fine to make small improvements like this.

Comment: @humble.rumble I agree with your qualifying statement. As a < 2k user, I feel like it is "our" responsibility to learn *how to make constructive edits*. The rep reward being experienced users' way of saying "well done, that was the right way to edit a post". I think title improvements on spelling *are* necessary, but like you said should be done post-2k.

Comment: For me if I see a suggested edit that I deem trivial, I will reject and edit (to send a message) to fix anything else that may be wrong with the post, if theres nothing else wrong, I skip and let someone else (hopefully) find something else worth fixing

Comment: I'm usually very tempted to correct a spelling error in the Title, much less so in the body.  I believe spelling corrections in the body are not justified as the only reason for edit as long as the question is generally understandable "as is".

Comment: @Jongware When an edit is approved by "Community" it means that a reviewer has clicked on "Improve Edit", the original edit is automatically approved. I don't think there's any validation when a reviewer takes this action.

Comment: FYI: I readily approve of correcting spelling errors of keywords in a post title even if that is the only  change.

Comment: I think sometimes this happens when users search for common misspellings, hoping to correct those misspellings in a ton of posts, rather than correcting all the low-hanging-fruit in each post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I looked into this a bit and I can't see anything to suggest that this is a coordinated scheme of abuse.

Theoretically a user with > 2K could abuse the edit review system to bootstrap sock puppets by hitting improve on all of them. If that were the case I'd usually expect:

1. Other heavy cross voting to show in mod tools. Other signs from mod tools.
2. The user making the edits to have low rep (mostly socks seem to stop gaining rep below about 100)
3. The edits the "improving" reviewer makes take almost no time/thought to make.

I don't see anything as evidence for any of those checks in this case, so it seems likely that everyone involved here was just doing their thing.

Probably the reviewer shouldn't have ticked "this edit was helpful" when improving, but that's not terribly major.

Comment: "Other heavy cross voting". There's been some discussion recently of the likelihood of puppets voting up "ordinary" users as well as their master, for "camouflage". If you have access to cross-voting patterns, then camouflage won't help, yes?

Comment: That sounds very sensible.  Digging in to the *Suggested Edits* showed a lot of repeat approvals from reviewers - but a closer analysis of times just showed many of the reviewers to be plowing through reviews in relatively quick succession. And that just leads back into the robo-reviewer conversations.

Comment: Then again, I just read the accepted answer to [“Too minor” edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253512/3773066) where the consensus is to approve edits fixing spelling in titles for search purposes, or to improve such edits.  In light of that, I guess my concern is trivial.

Comment: @OhBe relating to [that other post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site): even though it got the most votes, and **I** happen to agree with it, you should realise that it is a very contentious emotional issue. There is a lot to be gained from reading the other answers, and the comments too.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Yes indeed.  A lot of good points on each side.  I find my opinion to be a mesh of these the more I read.

Comment: @BillWoodger even 1/3 checks looking odd would be enough to dig around further.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the feedback.