# User suggesting needless edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

A particular user has been suggesting unnecessary edits for the past few days. All that user does is removing the code that was present in the question, and then pasting it back. There is absolutely no change otherwise. And for the description of the edit, the person mentions "Improved Formatting".

The code is already very well formatted, and the user makes no additional formatting improvements at all. As far as approving/rejecting the edits is concerned, I have done whatever seems fit by looking at whether there are any additional improvements.

Should I report this user's behavior? If yes, how?

Comment: If he gets enough edits refused (hopefully if the edits are as you say, that's just a matter of time) he'll be banned from editing altogether

Comment: I don't think you need to report him, he'll eventually get banned like @Patrice said, *btw hello P, good day*

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Ok.. The edit is not really a spam attempt then. I will look at markdowns too. Recently I've been looking only at the rendered output of the edit and that made edits seem unreasonable. I'll start considering both. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this question getting down-voted though?

Comment: That's an answer we will never be able to obtain @displayName

Comment: @edrodriguez: Why so? The answer is there and it's mentioned down below.

Comment: *"Why is this question getting down-voted though?"* I was replying to that comment @displayName

Comment: @displayName Edrodriquez meant we'll never be able to obtain an answer to the question _"Why is this question getting down-voted though?"_ Unless the down-voters comment and explain why they downvoted, we have zero way of knowing. They weren't giving you the reason the question was downvoted.

Comment: @Kendra: Oh!... :D Silly me.. :D

Comment: What I meant is, we will never be able to know the reasoning behind a down-vote. Since really no explanation is needed. It could be because someone doesn't think its a good question or just cause it's Monday. That's why I said we won't know the answer as to why it's down-voted. Since -for me- it truly seems like a legitimate question here on meta @displayName

Comment: Obligatory downvote reason: [Tim lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/280467)

Comment: @pnuts: That which has happened to you in that question of yours, is really bad. Already 34 down-votes and then 12 more... It's like *kicking a man when he's down.* :D :)

Comment: @pnuts - I got kicked for asking the same question about a question of mine.  People then seemed to purposely go to back to the original question and add more downvotes.  Then whoever was posting on meta started beating me up for having asked, saying I should have just moused over the arrows to find out.  It really turned me off.  Not just here, but gave me a poor feeling about people...  Oh well.  At least I got some good programming help.  And my edits of other questions were deemed useful (I worked hard on them to figure out the cryptic questions, so I was hoping they would.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You mean like [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9660708)? If you click in the markdown diff, you'll notice the suggestions add an HTML comment for syntax highlighting. That by itself is not the most useful thing in the world, but it is potentially a minor improvement. I personally think it's not enough of an improvement; I think it fits the "No improvement/superfluous" rejection reason.

However it's not malicious, and it seems to be a (lazy) *honest attempt* at improving stuff. [As other comments have noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306980/user-suggesting-needless-edits#comment252047_306980), if that user keeps making these poor suggestions, (s)he'll get edit banned in their own. Well, as long as reviewers are doing their jobs. Hopefully, after a few rejections that user will figure out what edits are appropriate on their own.

---

Addendum in case the user does not improve the quality of their edits or they are not banned. If all of the following are true:

- You continue to see these suggestions because reviewers keep approving them
- You are absolutely sure that the user is spamming the same kind of suggestions ([serial minor edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258459/4320665))
- Those suggestions should all have been rejected

you can follow [bluefeet's advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258334/4320665) and flag one of the posts with an approved suggested edit (emphasis mine):

> When you flag for moderator attention, just include some details about the issue. I'd suggest including a few links to some of the suggested edits and explain that the user suggested many incorrect edits and reviewers approved them. **Moderators can ban users from suggesting edits, and they can ban reviewers who approved them**.

Since you mention that the user has done this "for the past few days" it might be appropriate to flag their behavior. In general when you first encounter these kinds of edits, **you should hesitate to report the user's behavior.**

Comment: I am not sure how well the reviewers are doing their jobs.  The user has +126 rep so far today just adding language tags to code.

Comment: @displayName it means they have had 63 of these same edits approved so far today.  every time you get an approved suggest edit you get +2 reputation.

Comment: @displayName My issue is that if all of the edits they are doing is just adding the language tag to the code then they are just rep farming and should be stopped.  IMHO just added language formatting is not enough of an edit.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I agree with you about that.

Comment: Just an addition: I am usually generous for approving edits when someone makes some useful contribution. In my opinion, we shouldn't worry whether the user is rep-farming or not. We should treat each edit at its merit. Even if they are rep-farming but providing "useful" edits, they deserve that +2.

Comment: Do note that mods now _can_ ban a user from suggesting edits. I'll try to find the link to that on MSE, but that's been in the past couple months here. Edit: [Found it!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252991)

Comment: @Kendra nice to know.  We'll have to get bluefeet to update her answer in the linked post then.

Comment: Please note that adding language syntax coloring is not how you should edit posts. If the question is properly tagged with the specific language, the site will automatically pick correct syntax coloring. So the correct way to edit is to add the missing language tag to the question.

Comment: This. Look at the Markdown before complaining about an edit.

Comment: I am unaware of any evidence that mods want to get flagged because of serial minor edits.  The changes to the edit review queue have all been towards "allow even the most ridiculous of small improvements to be approved" despite general meta consensus the other way.

Comment: @blujay What are you responding to?

Comment: Is there a way to communicate directly to the user?  After all, they may not realize and an honest and clear and kind comment to them, may solve the problem.  (A hurtful or rude one won't fix anything of course.)

Comment: @curls: `@` notifications on the question will reach the user. They aren't in the suggested list, but if you actually type their username, they'll get notified. Editors are on the notification list for the posts they edit.

Comment: TJCrowder - can you explain that more clearly?  I've noticed I'm doing something not right.  Namely that I use @ so and so and the name and @ disappear.  Yet the comments box says to use @ and reference the person you are commenting to.  Also, does the user's name have to be typed exactly as they typed it?   I don't know what you mean by well, by any of your phrases.  I'm too new.  What's not on the suggested list?  Where's that list?  What editors?  The person gets notification if they've edited a question but the edit was rejected but a comment is added to the question to tell them why?

Comment: I'm writing to see if this goes to @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @curls: (Your second one pinged me) When you see the `@` and name disappear, you're running into [this "feature"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment): Atwood decided that he knows better than you whether it's appropriate social behavior to include that when you're addressing the OP (and Shog9 has chosen to keep it). The rules for whether it gets removed are arbitrary and relate to whether there are comments from others in-between. When you're not addressing the OP, it will remain.

Comment: "he knows better than you whether it's appropriate social behavior"  @ T.J. Crowder I hope that was a sarcastic comment at Atwood.  Because if it was a genuine comment at me, it's highly insulting and quite insane since there's nothing inappropriate about my trying to use the advice in the comments box telling me how to use this site :).  You aren't OP but it disappeared, so it's not just at the OP, which makes it quite silly to remove.  So far I've found if I include the 'at' in the middle of the cmt  somewhere,it picks up better.  Does the name need to be retyped exactly??

Comment: Can I ask one more question here so I don'[ have to post it and get dinged for asking a dup.  How do you raise something to moderator's attention?  I can't seem to get a search that says or see a way.  @ T.J. Crowder  Thanks.

Comment: @curls Flag --> other (in need of moderator attention).  Be sure to be specific in what you want the mods to do.  They will decline any flags that are unclear or are actions that don't require moderator intervention.

Comment: Thanks @ryanyuyu.  I'm still confused.  If I want to flag a question (and a whole series of comments to it) and raise it to moderator's attention, how do I do that?  Where would "Flag --> other (in need of moderator attention)" be posted or.  OOh, I bet you mean that I should hit the flag.  So for a question, it's next to the edit option.  Can I flag my own question in order to get moderation to look at a whole string of stuff going on with it, or will that ding me in the end to flag my own question?  Also do I need to include exact spelling of other people for the @ to work?

Comment: @curls that's a lot of questions.  But yes the flag option next the edit is correct.  Also, you can leave a custom flag on a comment (the flag is near the comment upvote) asking a mod to deal with an entire comment section.  Here's an MSE post on [How comment replies work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: It was two questions.  That's not a lot.  #@ryanuyu.  Thanks for the link on how comments work.  I didn't realize that flagging one comment can be used to ask mods to look at the whole string of comments.  My 2nd question that i've asked a couple times now that was germain to this whole exchange was: Also do I need to include exact spelling of other people for the @ to work?

Comment: I'll go back to my thought relative to this OP's post.  Is there a way to communicate directly to the user? After all, they may not realize and an honest and clear and kind comment to them, may solve the problem. (A hurtful or rude 1 won't fix anything of course.)  I don't mean that as "how do you comment to them."  I mean it as a suggestion that rather than rejecting their edits in silence, to have a way to respond to them for the edits with discussion and communication. I doubt that's through comments to the question they've edited. My thought being that communication trumps "implied" hints.

Comment: @curls the closest thing is the rejection reason.  If the users review their suggestions, they can see approval votes and rejection votes with reasons.  Reviewers can also leave a custom reason instead of one of the default ones.

Comment: Thank you.   Do I need to include exact spelling of other people for the @ to work?  @ryanyuyu  (Oh interesting, this time the name popped up so I could click on it -- that would solve the exact spelling if it happened every tiem.  I've never seen it before.)  But same question - exact spelling needed?

Comment: @cur It depends.  You really should read up on that or ask a new meta question.  This discussion (about comment replies) has gotten quite a bit off-topic of this question (about suggested edits).

Comment: It was a simple question and a yes or no would have done about 5 exchanges ago started with the other person.  There's no reason to make it challenging for someone or make them dig for a simple answer.  I won't ask a meta question.  I got beaten up horribly and nastily for doing so both times in the past.  It was gross.  As for this question, you just answered it.  You wrote cur and my id is curls, but showed up as notice to me.  So as long as it makes sense in the sequence it doesn't matter. @ryanyuyu  The pop up of the name doesn't place near where you're typing so it's a bug.

Comment: On the OP's question.  My suggestion then is to use the edit response tools to communicate with the editor and see if they didn't understand the process.... or have some logic that's not showing through.

Answer (score 25):

For what it is worth, [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) has had a bit of a problem with regard to syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow. See my post about it here: [What's happening to syntax highlighting for [css] questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121816/whats-happening-to-syntax-highlighting-for-css-questions) So for anyone wondering if this specific issue could be solved by changing the default language hint to lang-css, the answer is no because it would break syntax highlighting for a completely different set of questions.

This is not the first time a user has made a series of suggested edits solely to add the lang-css hint, and that is the reason why it happens. While I normally wouldn't *mind* these edits, it is pretty disappointing that this particular user couldn't be bothered to write a meaningful description, even to copy and paste — they just stuck with the "improved formatting" placeholder. I feel like I would reject these edits on grounds that the editor simply isn't putting effort into their edits for this reason.

But in general, as ryanyuyu has said, if there are more areas that can be improved that were clearly ignored by the editor then the edits should be summarily rejected as not fixing enough outstanding issues, because that too signals a lack of effort on the editor's part.

Comment: That is right. If the editor would leave one good hint in the description, I wouldn't be asking this question at all. I always read the description when I don't understand the purpose of an edit.

Comment: One problem I noticed with things like CSS is that there is only one "default highlight language" per post. So if you have some HTML and some CSS in one post, both code blocks will be highlighted using the same rules.

Comment: @MrLister If you have multiple languages, don't use default highlight. Instead, set the language manually for each code block.

Comment: @Mr Lister: "default" is more like "auto" - the syntax highlighter tries to figure out what language a specific code block is in and highlights it accordingly. The real problem is that the highlighter can't distinguish a CSS snippet. And that is why CSS requires a language hint, be it associated with the tag, or with an explicit comment in the Markdown source.

Comment: @Oriol That's why I like stack-snippets so much! Even though they insert the code into the post the wrong way round. But my comment was more a reflection on existing posts, where if the OP doesn't know about the `<!-- language -->` trick, al but one of the code blocks will come out wrong. That's maybe what triggered this specific person's editing spree.

Comment: @Mr Lister: You mean the way they insert CSS before HTML? It makes sense if you think about it - stylesheets go into the head element, which precedes body, and the HTML pane represents the contents of the body element only.

Answer (score 4):

Where syntax highlighting is absent but would be an improvement then adding an appropriate HTML comment is *good*, so should be encouraged.

I have quite often edited posts for that reason and no other. I have seen others have done so too. What I have *not* seen – as far as I can recall, so far – is complaints about that. Which is significant because someone at least on SO has managed to complain about practically everything else I have done here.

*Editing* is not the issue, rather *suggesting edits* - because these come to the attention of reviewers. If *You continue to see these suggestions because reviewers keep approving them* there is no issue. The Suggested Edits review queue is often down to `0` - the system is clearly handling the volume adequately – and the improvements (HTML comments) have been made. **No cause to flag.**

If other problems with the post are not corrected at the same time, that also is no issue. At least the post is better than it was. There is (almost) always the option of further edits/edit suggestions if further tidying is appropriate.

If there are no other problems with the post, that also is no issue. Job done.

If, as a reviewer, you don’t want to see incomplete edit suggestions that I understand. But it is quite simple really, hit <kbd>Skip</kbd>. And if that is too onerous, don’t review – there are plenty of others who will. And unless others do, skipping has the same effect as rejecting anyway.

Better of course is to click on <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> - win-win. Suggester has saved you adding the syntax highlighting element and all improvements are made. Job done. This is consistent with flagging, ie to bring to the notice of others what needs attention but cannot be unilaterally fixed by the user. Flagging, used properly is also *good*.

If *you* however can’t be bothered to see things through to completion you should not reject an improvement just because the person suggesting an edit also was not comprehensive. That leaves the post in a worse state than it might have become and sends the wrong message about what does and does not count as an improvement.

But your first question is *“Should I report this user's behavior?”*, the answer to which is **NO** (so your second question irrelevant).

Comment: I asked this question not because the user was doing incomplete edits or because it was onerous task for me. It seemed like the user was copy-pasting the code which I now understand was actually the language hint to help with code-color (It isn't obvious in the Rendered Output view). Moreover the user provided no hint in the description about his/her edit. It really seemed like an attempt to make undue rep points and I condoned this behavior for 3-4 days.

Comment: Ensuring that code has the correct syntax highlighting is a good thing, but IMO it's too trivial to require the time of 4 people, so users with under 2k rep should be discouraged from making such edits, unless they are also improving the post in other ways. So choosing "Improve Edit" is a great idea - it means that no more reviewers will waste time on it and (AFAIK) the original editor won't get the 2 points, discouraging them from making further trivial edits. But I guess it may be a good idea to ping the original editor with a brief comment saying why such edits are discouraged.