# Serial editor prepending "language: lang-m" to code

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I was presented with several edit suggestions in the review queue from this user, who is apparently on a hunt for questions new and old in which he can prepend `<!-- language: lang-m -->` to the code examples.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548707/sahils?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

I'm unsure whether this type of editing spree is to be encouraged. I noticed a few previous edits were accepted, but usually with at least one "no improvement whatsoever" rejection. 
I'd be interested to hear the opinion of more seasoned reviewers.

Comment: For a moment, I thought this was another case of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306980/user-suggesting-needless-edits But based on animuson's observations, this one seems quite different.

Comment: The reason I asked was that many answers on meta tell people to fix problems when they come across them, but to not go hunting for occurrences of a particular problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most of the edits seem to be properly formatting code which wasn't formatted before (was being displayed as plain-text). The lang-m thing is likely a character count bypass so that their edit will be submitted (there are a few that otherwise wouldn't have gone through). The comment isn't really doing anything and won't be displayed, so it's not exactly harmful. So just judge the edits like you would normally - does it make the post better and easier to read?

Comment: Is `lang-m` recognized by the code prettifier?  And if so, what language's rules does it apply?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, it is synonymous to the C family of syntax highlighting.

Comment: Apparently MS once developed a language called M, and there's also a C# generating tool called M#. But none of the edited posts is about M or M#; the most common language tag seems to be objective-c. So what would be the rationale for adding `lang-m` instead of `lang-c`?

Comment: @m69 The questions seem to be mostly (all?) Objective-C. Objective C files have a `.m` extension by default. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: @PaulRoub Thanks, I didn't know objective-c uses the `.m` extension.

Comment: Should I accept one of the answers, or is that not important on meta? This answer and @Glorfindel 's are saying roughly the same, so I wouldn't know how to choose one over the other.

Answer (score 19):

Well, the consensus seems to be that [minor edits are good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site). This particular edit, although small, enables code highlighting, which is a good improvement IMO. I'm glad I'm doing my Java development in Eclipse instead of Notepad.

If the missing highlighting is the *only* thing that can be improved, then by all means, go ahead and approve the edit. It's not that the edit-queue is already swamped with edits to review. If there are other major problems with the post, you should definitely reject (or improve & reject) the edit.

Answer (score 4):

If I was going to complain about anything, it's that in 4/10 of his most recent edits there were other minor things (spelling, capitalization, odd punctuation, chattiness) that should've been cleaned up at the same time.  However the user's profile suggests English may not be his(?) native language, and none of the issues I saw were egregious.