# Why this suggested edit with seemingly no changes has been approved?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits, review-abuse

I'm not sure what to think of [this edit to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14307084). I see no changes whatsoever. The updater has basically copied over what was already there. It's been rejected by two users with that exact motivation. Still, someone approved it.

That raises two questions.

1. Should we address the approving users?
2. Should we address the user who submitted this edit?

Likely, this isn't the only occasion when the user's done it.

Comment: The edit changed the language used by the code prettifier for the code blocks.  Whether it's actually the correct language (and whether it was incorrect before the edit) I couldn't comment.

Comment: Related / duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307394/4751173

Comment: Related: [Syntax highlight only edits are often helpful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314758/is-serially-editing-posts-to-include-syntax-highlighting-helpful)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take a look at the markdown view to see what changes have been made:

[image]

As you can see, this edit added syntax highlighting for the code, so I don't think it was approved incorrectly.

Comment: Technically, no - `lang-csh` is for the C Shell; `lang-cs` is the correct tag here, for C#. I tweaked the tweak. (they're both C-like, so the highlighting may actually be the same, anyway)

Comment: The code was highlighted prior to the change too, based on the tags in the question. Making the code beautified is a great idea, I agree. But in this case it wasn't needed. Was it?

Comment: @AndyJ No it wasn't.

Comment: You are correct. I stand corrected. Thanks, mate.