# What should I do about a user who keeps suggesting questionable edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've noticed a user (ID [5022812](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5022812)) who's been here for three years, but has, in the last three days, started suggesting lots of edits (56 at the moment) with a similar pattern:

- Adding pointless whitespace into the post, e.g. [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22834038), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22834040), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22823222), [#4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22829828), [#5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22834457). In fact I think all but two of the 56 edits insert spaces (typically at least 20 consecutive spaces).

  Here's #1 which adds **33**(!) spaces at the end of one line, doesn't fix the indentation of the code, doesn't remove the fluff at the end, and doesn't fix the formatting of `ViewModel constructor` which isn't code (I rejected this suggested edit and fixed the issues).

  > [image: bad suggested edit #1]

  This spacing irks me the most - is it to get around a minimum character limit imposed on edits? Or is it some weird quirk of the user?
- `Formatting` random `programming` words as `code` even if they're not code (e.g. [#6](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22829828), which also doesn't format the `public` keyword as code):

  > [image: bad suggested edit #6]
- The "Edit Summary" text for all the edits (where it's not system-generated, e.g. "*added 713 characters in body*" is **always** dots - at least, this is what the first two pages of the overview in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5022812/hassan-ef?tab=activity&sort=revisions) page for the user shows.

To be clear, I have **no** issue with a user suggesting dozens of edits a day and getting the associated reputation benefits from it — when they are **good** edits. This user appears to have almost exclusively suggested edits which don't appear to even try to fix the issues with the posts being edited.

At the moment, this user's stats are:

> {5022812} had 41 edit suggestions approved, and 19 edit suggestions rejected

so presumably they'll get an edit ban if their ratio gets much worse, but what could be done before that happens?

Is this behaviour I should flag? If not, what action should I take?

---

**Rebuttal to the Possible duplicate of "[User suggesting needless edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306980/1364007)" close vote(s)**

I did see (and read) that question before I posted this one. I didn't want to post a duplicate question so spent a while searching to try to find questions which covered what I was going to ask.

I don't think that this is enough of a duplicate of the that question for the following reasons:

1. As [Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/792066/braiam) pointed out in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384190/what-should-i-do-about-a-user-who-keeps-suggesting-questionable-edits#comment691123_384190) below, the other question turned out to be because the user was adding syntax highlighting for code, e.g.

   ```
   <!-- language: lang-css -->
   ```

   to posts which were otherwise fine. This is not the case here, as the suggested edits are to posts which require further editing (e.g. in the two screenshots I provided above).
2. The three answers to the other question **all** relate to adding syntax highlighting, which is perfectly acceptable (and normal) behaviour. Again, this is not the case here. There is some syntax highlighting, but some of it is for `random` words which aren't code but are `programming` terms (e.g. the second screenshot).
3. The edits that my question asks about almost **all** have what I describe as "*pointless whitespace*" added to the posts. In the five examples in my first bullet point, there are a total of 140 bizzare whitespace characters added to the end of of lines - both code lines and non-code lines. I suspected that this was to evade minimum suggested edit character changes. This is not covered in the other question.

Comment: Reject the edits with a custom reason: 'Your suggestion has nothing to do with the edit summary you provided.' Or 'A potentially valid suggestion which has nothing to do whatsoever with the edit summary'. If you see many edits, mod-flag and move on. Let the user to mods.

Comment: Bad edits tend to be a self-solving problem (as the user is supposed to be edit-banned soon). But if they are flying  under the radar or they are getting their trashy edits approved, flag. A mod will probably look at their edit history, and at the reviewers actions as well.

Comment: I've personally flagged weird, mass editing behavior before. Use a custom flag on a post they've edited and explain the issue. As yiv just pointed out, it's worth doing if the edits are getting approved or if this appears out of character for the user, like if they normally do good edits or normally don't edit at all and then suddenly a ton of nonsense.

Comment: They've been members for three years, but only recently became active. So apart from a lonely question on 2015, they are a "new" user and they are still learning how the site operates.

Comment: They seem already close to hitting an edit ban. The ban kicks in when in the past week, the user has five more rejected edits than one-third of their approved edits. Assuming that all their suggested edits are in the past week (there are four to deleted posts which I can't see in the activity history), they've *technically* just hit it, but at least one of those rejections is an automatic one due to an edit conflict. Just keep rejecting their edits; they'll soon be banned.

Comment: @double-beep instead of specifying a custom reason I sometimes Reject and Edit - putting a rejection reason in my own edit summary which includes the URL of the suggested edit, e.g. [a](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55824210/2), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55823954/2). I've done this in the past when a bad suggested edit has approvals or if the suggestion is sufficiently bad - but when I think about it, it doesn't give a good reason in the suggested edit review view.

Comment: I think I will raise a custom flag - unless a mod answers this question first. The behaviour is weird and we probably shouldn't allow it.

Comment: I agree that a lot of their edits are questionable, but the added whitespaces itself are imho not really a problem. If the edit is otherwise fine, I'd suggest accepting them.

Comment: I suggest next time you mod flag something like this directly. Now the meta effect probably has kicked in and some users might have started moderating the specific user instead of specific content. Cases like this are best resolved by a moderator, hence a custom flag is warranted. Personally I tend to leave a comment under one of their posts to ask them to better their behaviour, this sometimes does the trick. If not modflag is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @Luuklag - I didn't want any meta effect so deliberately didn't *name* the user - just referred to them through their ID. I wanted to post links to some suggested edits but couldn't anonymise them, so went with that compromise.

Comment: HTML comment openers (`<!--`) can be used to get around the character limit without leaving a trace. Anything other method should be considered vandalism, unless it leaves no trace.

Comment: @alec_a Adding HTML coments to get around the character limit is also an abuse of the system. It's not fine because "it leaves no trace".

Comment: @yivi iI there's a simple error in a small post, html comments help push the edit through. I used them a ton under 2000 rep and nobody said anything to me, but if I'm wrong a mod can correct me.

Comment: Obviously using them to push unconstructive edits through is not ok

Comment: @alec I'm not a mod, but I don't have to to be able to tell you that you are wrong. The character limit is there for a purpose. Adding noise to circumvent the system limit is an abuse of the system, and it is well documented.

Comment: Probably they are seeking points for editing, but that of course is speculative.

Comment: The added trailing spaces (that do not help wrt. the minimum character count) could be an attempt to add an extra empty line (but that only works in the edit window in the browser or mobile app...). Or in this case perhaps to align the `{` (again, only in edit window).  This is often seen done by inexperienced users (and some never learn, even after 3 years).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User suggesting needless edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306980/user-suggesting-needless-edits) (Seriously, people. Lots of you are long time SO members active on Meta. Why didn't you mark this as a dupe of something?)

Comment: @jpmc26 "You mean like this suggestion? If you click in the markdown diff, you'll notice the suggestions add an HTML comment for syntax highlighting." because this.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - hmm - yeah, I think you might be right about the spaces. Just came across [another instance](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22847191) where the user inserted numerous spaces at the end of a line for no apparent reason.

Comment: @jpmc26 I added a rebuttal to the end of my question (too long to fit in a comment). I don't think that my question is enough of a duplicate of the linked question to warrant closure.

Comment: @Braiam It's a dupe of probably hundreds of questions on SO. I just picked one. The answer is there: "In case the user does not improve the quality of their edits or they are not banned, ... you can follow bluefeet's advice and flag one of the posts." That is the answer for *all* repeated problematic behaviors; we don't need a thousand different answers saying so.

Comment: I am so sorry about my rejected edit, I created my account 3 years ago but I try to collaborate here just two weeks ago and ofcourse I am a little new here and I didnt know how to do something right but I found something and dont do wrong for this time to next. thanks for all of your attention.

Comment: @hassan.ef - First of all, thanks for your comment. I saw that [Samuel Liew ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew) posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55784069/listing-of-data-in-many-to-many-table-relations-using-net-mvc-5/55805061#comment98319728_55805061) on one of your answers and I was hoping you'd comment here. There's no need to be sorry. I hope that you don't feel victimised by this post: I deliberately didn't mention you by name to avoid this. As I mentioned in my question I have no problem people editing posts - provided that they're good edits. 1/2

Comment: Also - you've probably already seen it, but I think it might be worth your while to read the [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) page in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for some guidance on how to approach editing posts so that you can avoid having your future suggested edits rejected. Thanks again for commenting here. 2/2

Comment: @ Wai Ha Lee thanks for you, it's helpful for me that I dont wrong again.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If this is a recurring pattern by the user, like adding random code formatting to words that are not code (for emphasis, etc.), rejecting the individual edits is not enough. These kind of edits are a form of mass vandalism, even though the editor could mean well. So it is important that someone reaches out to them and tell them to stop, and that's the job of moderators.

- Copy the link to the suggested edit.
- Open up the post where they made one such incorrect edit. Flag that post with a custom reason for diamond moderator attention.
- Write "user x is making multiple incorrect edits such as `<paste link>`". Additionally, you may consider adding a link to this Meta question, as it will provide context.
- Moderators will investigate and take action if needed.
- You won't get notified about their actions, other than having your flag marked as helpful once the matter is investigated.

It is *not* necessary to manually roll back the misguided edits that may have slipped through review. Moderators can overrule an edit approval, which will revert any reputation gain, but this *only* works if there haven't been any edits made in the meantime.

Comment: when I am flagging troublesome edits I also typically add to flag message suggestion to do something about robo reviewers who approve these

Comment: Thanks for this. I have raised a custom flag. I didn't mention the reviewers who accepted the suggested edits as I didn't have enough characters to do so, partly because (a) presumably if a moderator is looking at it they'll also investigate the reviewers, and (b) it's not just one reviewer accepting these answers (I don't think I saw the same accepting user twice) and I don't have the time at the moment to look at individual reviewers.

Comment: @gnat The mods are well-aware of that problem too though. They'll probably look at the reviewers too.

Comment: agree, I also think they typically do this. Still I prefer to add such a reminder to make sure that they won't miss it

Comment: My flag was marked "helpful". I flagged a post with an accepted bad edit on it. The text I added was: "{5022812} appears to have only made questionable suggested edits (e.g. here). Many of them insert weird whitespace (typically 20-30 spaces at the end of lines), all of them have `...........` as the edit summary, and most of them just target specific parts of the edited posts but leave glaring issues behind. More details in my question about this user on Meta [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384190), where the consensus was to flag.".

Comment: Actually, you *shouldn't* do manual rollbacks of the changes. Moderators can overrule an edit approval, which will revert any reputation gain, but this *only* works if there haven't been any edits made in the meantime.

Comment: Since everyone's editing my answer left and right, I'll turn it into a community wiki.

Comment: @CodyGray You're assuming most mods will actually do that in practice. That's not been my experience; in fact, I don't think I've ever personally witnessed this power being used, only mentioned on Meta. When I posted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313517/1709587, for instance, BoltClock banned the user in question but didn't overrule any approvals; I had to go on my own lengthy rollback spree. Perhaps a sensible compromise is to wait until after your flag has been handled before doing rollbacks, thus giving a mod the chance to do them if they're inclined to.

Comment: That option didn't exist back in 2015, @Mark. It's a relatively new feature. I've used it quite frequently for plagiarized tag wikis. I've also used it many, many times to roll back edits giving a bunch of posts Lyme disease. Other moderators use it, too. Unfortunately, it is of limited usefulness because you can only override approval/rejections if the post hasn't been edited in the meantime. They often are. So in that case, a manual rollback is necessary. Still, I'd say let the moderator do that.