# Suggested edit claims to have been made by a bot?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-abuse

I came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10108278) in the review queue today.

The review comment contains "Added relevant tags. [Edit made by a bot (owner @ArtOfCode): algorithm revision 2015.11.05.21B]" and does nothing more than add the [layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout) tag. I rejected the edit and also flagged the question for moderator attention.

Is there a policy in place regarding automation and using bots on Stack Overflow? I can't imagine this type of activity being allowed on the site.

Comment: For context: [Is TaggerBot a good idea?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309463/is-taggerbot-a-good-idea)