# Is it appropriate to use meta to solicit feedback on improving automation?

Tags: discussion, meta

A while ago, I started a project - TaggerBot. Some may remember it from [Is TaggerBot a good idea?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309463/is-taggerbot-a-good-idea).

It has developed from that stage, and has got better. However, it's been getting better through my own ideas, which may not always be the best or even *right*.

I'd like to ask for *specific, directed* feedback on how I could improve the system. For example, I've implemented a database that is used to blacklist tags that the bot should never suggest, and I've added some tags to it that I think shouldn't be used - but I'm never going to get all of them. If I were to ask a question here on Meta about what tags I should blacklist, I'd be able to get a lot more input to make the system even better.

To clarify, these are not *programming* or *implementation* questions - I would be asking for meta-feedback or ideas to improve, rather than assistance or ideas on actually *making* the system.

Now, debates about the bot itself's usefulness aside, is this something that Meta would be OK with?

---

Thanks for the feedback. I have now gone and created a chatroom - come and join me: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31772/taggerbots-development-room

Comment: Hmmm, borderline a bit. On the one hand TaggerBot is kind of a Meta tool, on the other hand this is a programming related question directly related to your tool. Not so sure if you should ask this on Meta-SO. Also I'm not sure if asking for improvements should be asked at Stack Overflow, but rather at SE CodeReview or SE Programmers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ To clarify, these are not programming questions I want to ask. They're asking for meta-feedback on the bot system, rather than assistance making it. I'm just concerned whether the community here would take that well, or not, given it's a fairly uncommon type of question to ask.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It sounds more like asking for _ideas_ than asking for help with the code itself. Such as the tag "blacklist" idea mentioned in the question- That would be off-topic on those sites, and potentially on-topic here, depending on how it's worded.

Comment: OK, I probably misunderstood the goal of such potential question.

Comment: Best thing would be to have a [tag:featured] question on Meta IMHO, though I have no idea how you could make it one :-( ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  That's governed by a mod-only tag, and I doubt the mods would want to publish a third-party bot in this fashion when its usage is still morally questionable.

Comment: @Makoto Sure I'm aware it's a mod restricted tag.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I see no reason for a question like that to be featured.

Comment: @Servy Neither me, may be my comment was unclear.

Comment: For my bot, I created a chatroom and put a link to it in [my meta.math post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21799), indicating that this is where feedback can be sent (in addition to meta post itself).  I didn't really expect a lot of specific feedback to pour in; but I got a few suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I propose an alternative, since you are still early in developing this automation tool: Utilize chat.

Normal Human suggested this in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310479/is-it-appropriate-to-use-meta-to-solicit-feedback-on-improving-automation#comment272093_310479) and I believe it's the best option. Your automation is relevant to SO, but the *development* of the automation is more murky.

By holding discussions in chat, as other bot developers do, you have a specific room dedicated to the development of your automated process. It prevents repeated meta posts related to the same thing (ie. "TaggerBot: Do we blacklist?", "TaggerBot: Do we whitelist?", "TaggerBot: Do we X?", etc). With repeated posts, you risk user annoyance if it's to frequent. It allows users to throw up suggestions for the bot that need fleshing out or may be completely out of scope for what you want the bot to do.

A meta-post is good when the process is stable. Present the community with what you are doing, how it is helping (or not, and *then* solicit feedback), and other information on what it is doing to Stack Overflow and why the community should not be worried about a misguided bot.