# User is introducing several low quality wiki edits

Tags: discussion

This user [Sivaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3557336/sivaa-nethaji?tab=activity) has made several wiki edits today that I have rejected because they are copied content or other low quality edits. I have a concern that he is breaking the rules in a severe fashion but I don't know of a way to contact Moderator or flag his posts because that's not an options in the wiki review system. What should I do?

Comment: "Raise the issue on Meta." Oh, there you go.

Comment: Note, this question also deals with the same user: [Add ability to "flag" tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265877/add-ability-to-flag-tag-wiki)

Comment: Action has been taken, and the account has been temporarily suspended

Comment: For the record, you can flag these things for moderator attention by placing an "other" flag on one of their posts (or even yours) and link to them and explain things. This user was suspended for something unrelated to this while I was looking into their account.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: How long does it take to action on these flags? I have had a flag sitting for a couple days and some for much longer than that in an active state? I know the mantra is to flag but there is no clear guideline on when it will be actioned. The point is some moderators will tell you not to flag and others will rather you have the community handle it. For instance, I have 59 flags waiting review.

Comment: @staticx there can be no guideline because it depends on volume. And you flag when the community can't handle it. Editing a post vs a suspected cheater, for example. And keep in mind that "close flags" and low quality flags are not (necessarily) handled by mods.

Comment: @staticx I think all the Other flag's I've raised on abusive/etc accounts have been handled within an hour or two.  I'd estimate about 90% of my other flags are handled within 12 hours or less and most of the rest within a day.  And while I do have a few open flags that are a lot older; most of the times I've flagged something and it lingers more than a few days it ends up being disputed or declined.  Having that many flags open makes me think you might be overly trigger happy and might want to back down before getting an official warning like I did a few years ago.

Comment: @DanNeely: Flags for closing show up in the flag queue (as I learned). I am talking about a couple custom flags that have been lingering.

Comment: @staticx I just checked; all 54 of your open flags are 'close' flags.

Comment: My custom flags often take weeks (2 currently active, 8 days and 1.5 months).  Flag anyway; if it's a really big deal [bring it to meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252331/425313), and if it's a small issue don't worry about it.

Comment: This user is back from their suspension, has changed their display name, and has picked up right where they left off - copying content to tag wikis without attribution.